# Macro questions

Tags: c, macros

On a software project (some old C compiler) we have a lot of variables which have to be saved normal and inverted.

Has somebody a idea how i can make a macro like that?

```
SET(SomeVariable, 137);
```

which will execute

```
SomeVariable = 137;
SomeVariable_inverse = ~137;
```

Edit:

The best Solution seems to be:

```
#define SET(var,value) do { var = (value); var##_inverse = ~(value); } while(0)
```

Thanks for the answers

Comment: If you want to indicate that is the best solution, you should select that one as the "accepted" solution; that gives a reputation bonus to the user who contributed it, and marks it as the solution that solved your problem.

Comment: Should the macro also take the chance to ensure that var = ~var_inverse immediately before doing the assignment?  do { assert(var == ~var##_inverse); var = (value); var##_inverse = ~(value); } while (0).  If you use this macro everywhere, it is your best chance to check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One hazard I haven't seen mentioned is that the 'value' macro argument is evaluated twice in most of the solutions.  That can cause problems if someone tries something like this:

```
int x = 10;
SET(myVariable, x++);
```

After this call, myVariable would be 10 and myVariable_inverse would be ~11.  Oops.  A minor change to JaredPar's solution solves this:

```
#define SET(var,value) do { var = (value); var##_inverse = ~(var); } while(0)
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
#define SET(var,value) do { var = (value); var##_inverse = ~(value); } while(0)
```

**EDIT**

Couple of links to the reason behind adding a do/while into the macro

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for
- http://www.rtems.com/ml/rtems-users/2001/august/msg00111.html
- http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TrivialDoWhileLoop
- http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2008/05/21/do-while-0-what.aspx

Comment: Is there an article somewhere explaining why you use a macro construction out of a do loop?  I'm curious why...

Comment: In short: the do..while wrapping lets the macro as a whole behave as a statement, which is good. Think if/else, braces, and stuff.

Comment: The general idea is that you want a macro that will work just like a function call, which means you can write things like "SET(a, 1);" or "if (foo) SET(a, 1); else SET(a, 2);".  See http://c-faq.com/cpp/multistmt.html for details.

Comment: @Tom, I added a few links that go into detail about why this is good practice for multi-statement macros.

Comment: @dmckee, missed that one (added).

Comment: Just one minor thing should be added - using the ## token pasting operator needs to go through some macro indirection hoops to correctly handle cases where one or both operands is a macro itself. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216875/-in-macros/217181#217181

Comment: It may be theoretically a good solution but in 18+ yrs I've never seen it being necessary so I'd rather recommend something that makes the macro more readable to take away macros bad rep....

Answer (score 4):

Why are you storing the inverse when it can be so easily calculated? This seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: This is a security mesure. Every important variable has to be stored normal and inverse. Every second the variables get checked. If they are wrong hell breaks lose.

Comment: Might make sense in a environment with strong nuclear radiation. But I'm QUITE scared that a developer for embedded SW in such an environment has to ask that kind of question here.

Comment: There are beginners also in embedded SW development.

Comment: @nuriaion - in this case you need to make the updates & checks atomic (using a mutex or something) so all hell doesn't break loose if the check happens to occur between setting the value and setting the 'mirror' of the value.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in a single statement, which avoids having to use `do {} while (0)`.

```
#define SetInverse(token, value) (token##_inverse = ~(token = (value)))
```

Also, this only evalutes `(value)` once, which is always nice.

Comment: >> Also, this only evalutes (value) once, which is always nice << - definitely a worthwhile reason to use this method.

Comment: A slight modification makes this macro return the value of (value), just like if it were an assignment (just on the off chance it gets used in a larger expression itself, which is valid if probably unusual):  #define SetInverse(token, value) (token = ~(token##_inverse = ~(value)))

Comment: I was tempted to add a `(void)` cast to the define just to make sure it can't be used in a larger expression, but yeah, making it evaluate to `value` is pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define SetInverse(token, value) { token = value; token##_inverse = ~value; }
```

Jinx, Jared - like the while (0) in yours

Comment: This becomes a bit silly when used with the normal semicolon, SetInverse(a, 48); ends up creating a null statement in the code, which (to me) is far uglier than the do..while(0) loop.

Comment: I wondered if stringization could be useful, but I've never used it in anger and I couldn't see how it could be used here.  The docs say that ## prevents identifier replacement - does it really work in the middle of a contigious string?

Comment: Alas, `do{}while(0)` is necessary: this fails if written as `if (1) SetInverse(t, 0); else {printf("unmatched 'else'!\n");}`

Answer (score 0):

Just to offer an alternative method:

Store each variable as a structure like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    u32 u32Normal;
    u32 u32Inverted;
} SafeU32TYPE
```

Then have a function which takes a pointer to one of these, along with the value to be set, and stores that value with its inverse:

```
void Set(SafeU32TYPE *pSafeU32, u32Data)
{
    if(pSafeU32 != NULL)
    {
        pSafeU32->u32Normal = u32Data;
        pSageU32->u32Inverted = ~u32Data;
    } /* if */
} /* Set() */
```

**Advantage**: if you need the set function to do something more powerful, such as boundary checking, or storing in some more complex way, then it can be easily extended.

**Disadvantage**: you'll need a different function for each type used, and if processor resource is an issue, this is less efficient than using a macro.