# c++ MACRO undeclared identifier on dynamic variable

Tags: c++, imacros

I try to build dynamic string from counter variable in loop in c++ , I was thinking about simple `macro`.

**something like this :**

```
// its enum element string LOCAL_1, LOCAL_2 .....
    #define CREATE_STR(N) LOCAL_##N

    int ii =1;
        for(;ii<=COLS_NUMBERS_PER_WINDOW;)
        {
                     pGameObj->IniGameObj(pMainWindowObjCenter,
                                        CREATE_STR(ii),
                                        Z,                                   
                                        ii);
            GameVector.push_back(pGameObj);
            ii++;
        }
```

but it gives me compiler **error**

```
error C2065: 'LOCAL_ii' : undeclared identifier
```

Is there any other good way to build dynamic string from dynamic variable? I can use c++11.

**UPDATE:**
i think i just need this :
[Enum C++ Get by Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321801/enum-c-get-by-index)

Comment: Macros run before "normal" compilation, let alone during runtime.

Comment: I'm hopping that this is what you were referring to.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806543/c-macros-manipulating-a-parameter-specific-example

Comment: @chris: 
im getting :
cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' to 'GameObjectTypeLocation'
its enum type

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to tell what you're trying to do. But I'm guessing that you have something like `enum { LOCAL_1, LOCAL_2, ...`, and you want to convert `ii` to these symbols.

You definitely can't do this with the preprocessor. The value of `ii` is not even known at compile time, and because the preprocessor happens even before that, the best you can do is a simple text substitution, which makes it impossible to use `ii` as a changing expression like you want.

You have to do the expansion at runtime, like @Jarod42 suggests (`"LOCAL_" + std::to_string(ii)`), but then you're left with a string. At runtime, the compiler has since forgotten about symbols like `LOCAL_1`.

So back to square 1, how to convert `ii` to a `LOCAL_xx`? I would suggest the following:

If `LOCAL_xx` is an enum, then just assign the enum constants to the value you want to convert from `ii`.

```
enum {
    LOCAL_1 = 1,
    LOCAL_2 = 2,
};
```

Now, there is basically no difference between `ii` and `LOCAL_xxx`. No conversion is necessary.

If `LOCAL_xx` are not integer constants, then you will need to construct the mapping yourself. For example using `std::map<int, LOCAL_xxx>` or a big switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like

```
const GameObjectTypeLocation locals[COLS_NUMBERS_PER_WINDOW] = {
    LOCAL_1, LOCAL_2, LOCAL_3
};
for (int ii = 1; ii <= COLS_NUMBERS_PER_WINDOW; ++ii)
{
    pGameObj->IniGameObj(pMainWindowObjCenter, locals[ii - 1], Z, ii);
    GameVector.push_back(pGameObj);
}
```

if `LOCAL_1`, `LOCAL_2` follow a logic, you may convert the `int` into the `enum` directly.

```
for (int ii = 1; ii <= COLS_NUMBERS_PER_WINDOW; ++ii)
{
    // Assuming LOCAL_1 = 0, LOCAL_2 = 1, ...
    pGameObj->IniGameObj(pMainWindowObjCenter, GameObjectTypeLocation(ii - 1), Z, ii);
    GameVector.push_back(pGameObj);
}
```

As a note, with:

```
enum GameObjectTypeLocation { LOCAL_1, LOCAL_2};
```

`LOCAL_1` is `0`, `LOCAL_2` is `1`, ..

Comment: hehe Good idea simple, the thing is i already have the enum , i dont what to duplicate data