# How can I concatenate twice with the C preprocessor and expand a macro as in "arg ## _ ## MACRO"?

Tags: c, concatenation, token, c-preprocessor

I am trying to write a program where the names of some functions are dependent on the value of a certain macro variable with a macro like this:

```
#define VARIABLE 3
#define NAME(fun) fun ## _ ## VARIABLE

int NAME(some_function)(int a);
```

Unfortunately, the macro `NAME()` turns that into

```
int some_function_VARIABLE(int a);
```

rather than

```
int some_function_3(int a);
```

so this is clearly the wrong way to go about it. Fortunately, the number of different possible values for VARIABLE is small, so I can simply do an `#if VARIABLE == n` and list all the cases separately, but is there is a clever way to do it?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use function pointers instead?

Comment: @Jurily - Function pointers work at runtime, preprocessor works at (before) compile time. There is a difference, even if both can be used for the same task.

Comment: The point is that what it is used in is a fast computational geometry library.. which is hardwired for a certain dimension. However, sometimes someone would want to be able to use it with a few different dimensions (say, 2 and 3) and so one would need an easy way to generate code with dimension-dependent function and type names.

Also, the code is written in ANSI C so the funky C++ stuff with templates and specialization is not applicable here.

Comment: Voting to reopen because this question is specific about recursive macro expansion and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216875/using-in-macros is a generic "what it is good for". The title of this question should be made more precise.

Comment: I wish this example had been minimized: the same happens on `#define A 0 \n #define M a ## A`: having two `##` is not the key.

Answer (score 256):

#### Standard C Preprocessor

```
$ cat xx.c
#define VARIABLE 3
#define PASTER(x,y) x ## _ ## y
#define EVALUATOR(x,y)  PASTER(x,y)
#define NAME(fun) EVALUATOR(fun, VARIABLE)

extern void NAME(mine)(char *x);
$ gcc -E xx.c
# 1 "xx.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "xx.c"





extern void mine_3(char *x);
$
```

#### Two levels of indirection

In a comment to another answer, [Cade Roux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18255/cade-roux) [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-token-concatenation/1489985#comment1342105_1489971) why this needs two levels of indirection.  The flippant answer is because that's how the standard requires it to work; you tend to find you need the equivalent trick with the stringizing operator too.

Section 6.10.3 of the C99 standard covers 'macro replacement', and 6.10.3.1 covers 'argument substitution'.

> After the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro have been identified,
>   argument substitution takes place. A parameter in the replacement list, unless preceded
>   by a `#` or `##` preprocessing token or followed by a `##` preprocessing token (see below), is
>   replaced by the corresponding argument after all macros contained therein have been
>   expanded. Before being substituted, each argument’s preprocessing tokens are
>   completely macro replaced as if they formed the rest of the preprocessing file; no other
>   preprocessing tokens are available.

In the invocation `NAME(mine)`, the argument is 'mine'; it is fully expanded to 'mine'; it is then substituted into the replacement string:

```
EVALUATOR(mine, VARIABLE)
```

Now the macro EVALUATOR is discovered, and the arguments are isolated as 'mine' and 'VARIABLE'; the latter is then fully expanded to '3', and substituted into the replacement string:

```
PASTER(mine, 3)
```

The operation of this is covered by other rules (6.10.3.3 'The ## operator'):

> If, in the replacement list of a function-like macro, a parameter is immediately preceded
>   or followed by a `##` preprocessing token, the parameter is replaced by the corresponding
>   argument’s preprocessing token sequence; [...]
>
> For both object-like and function-like macro invocations, before the replacement list is
>   reexamined for more macro names to replace, each instance of a `##` preprocessing token
>   in the replacement list (not from an argument) is deleted and the preceding preprocessing
>   token is concatenated with the following preprocessing token.

So, the replacement list contains `x` followed by `##` and also `##` followed by `y`; so we have:

```
mine ## _ ## 3
```

and eliminating the `##` tokens and concatenating the tokens on either side combines 'mine' with '_' and '3' to yield:

```
mine_3
```

This is the desired result.

---

If we look at the original question, the code was (adapted to use 'mine' instead of 'some_function'):

```
#define VARIABLE 3
#define NAME(fun) fun ## _ ## VARIABLE

NAME(mine)
```

The argument to NAME is clearly 'mine' and that is fully expanded.
Following the rules of 6.10.3.3, we find:

```
mine ## _ ## VARIABLE
```

which, when the `##` operators are eliminated, maps to:

```
mine_VARIABLE
```

exactly as reported in the question.

---

#### Traditional C Preprocessor

[Robert Rüger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1746785/robert-r%c3%bcger) [asks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/how-to-concatenate-twice-with-the-c-preprocessor-and-expand-a-macro-as-in-arg/1489985?noredirect=1#comment69821433_1489985):

> Is there any way do to this with the traditional C preprocessor which does not have the token pasting operator `##`?

Maybe, and maybe not — it depends on the preprocessor.  One of the advantages of the standard preprocessor is that it has this facility which works reliably, whereas there were different implementations for pre-standard preprocessors.  One requirement is that when the preprocessor replaces a comment, it does not generate a space as the ANSI preprocessor is required to do.  The GCC (6.3.0) C Preprocessor meets this requirement; the Clang preprocessor from XCode 8.2.1 does not.

When it works, this does the job (`x-paste.c`):

```
#define VARIABLE 3
#define PASTE2(x,y) x/**/y
#define EVALUATOR(x,y) PASTE2(PASTE2(x,_),y)
#define NAME(fun) EVALUATOR(fun,VARIABLE)

extern void NAME(mine)(char *x);
```

Note that there isn't a space between `fun,` and `VARIABLE` — that is important because if present, it is copied to the output, and you end up with `mine_ 3` as the name, which is not syntactically valid, of course.  (Now, please can I have my hair back?)

With GCC 6.3.0 (running `cpp -traditional x-paste.c`), I get:

```
# 1 "x-paste.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "x-paste.c"





extern void mine_3(char *x);
```

With Clang from XCode 8.2.1, I get:

```
# 1 "x-paste.c"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 329 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "x-paste.c" 2





extern void mine _ 3(char *x);
```

Those spaces spoil everything.  I note that both preprocessors are correct; different pre-standard preprocessors exhibited both behaviours, which made token pasting an extremely annoying and unreliable process when trying to port code.  The standard with the `##` notation radically simplifies that.

There might be other ways to do this.  However, this does not work:

```
#define VARIABLE 3
#define PASTER(x,y) x/**/_/**/y
#define EVALUATOR(x,y) PASTER(x,y)
#define NAME(fun) EVALUATOR(fun,VARIABLE)

extern void NAME(mine)(char *x);
```

GCC generates:

```
# 1 "x-paste.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "x-paste.c"





extern void mine_VARIABLE(char *x);
```

Close, but no dice.  YMMV, of course, depending on the pre-standard preprocessor that you're using.  Frankly, if you're stuck with a preprocessor that is not cooperating, it would probably be simpler to arrange to use a standard C preprocessor in place of the pre-standard one (there is usually a way to configure the compiler appropriately) than to spend much time trying to work out a way to do the job.

Comment: Yep, this solves the problem. I knew the trick with two levels of recursion -- I had to play with stringification at least once -- but didn't know how to do this one.

Comment: Is there any way do to this with the [traditional C preprocessor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Traditional-macros.html) which does not have the token pasting operator ##?

Comment: @RobertRüger: it doubles the length of the answer, but I've added information to cover `cpp -traditional`.  Note that there isn't a definitive answer — it depends on the preprocessor you've got.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. This is totally great! In the meantime I also found another, slightly different solution. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41330134/1746785). It also has the problem that it doesn't work with clang though. Luckily that's not an issue for my application ...

Answer (score 35):

Use:

```
#define VARIABLE 3
#define NAME2(fun,suffix) fun ## _ ## suffix
#define NAME1(fun,suffix) NAME2(fun,suffix)
#define NAME(fun) NAME1(fun,VARIABLE)

int NAME(some_function)(int a);
```

Honestly, you don't want to know why this works.  If you know why it works, you'll become *that guy* at work who knows this sort of thing, and everyone will come ask you questions.  =)

Comment: Could you explain why it needs two levels of indirection.  I had an answer with one level of redirection but I deleted the answer because I had to install C++ into my Visual Studio and then it wouldn't work.

Comment: I want to become that guy at work who knows this sort of thing. :)

Answer (score 10):

**Plain-English explanation of the `EVALUATOR` two-step pattern**

I haven't fully understood every word of the C standard, but I think this is a reasonable working model for how the solution shown in [Jonathan Leffler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/how-can-i-concatenate-twice-with-the-c-preprocessor-and-expand-a-macro-as-in-ar/1489985#1489985) works, explained a little more verbosely. Let me know if my understanding is incorrect, hopefully with a minimal example that breaks my theory.

For our purposes, we can think of macro expansion as happening in three steps:

1. (prescan) Macro arguments are replaced:

   - if they are part of concatenation (`A ## B`) or stringification (`#A`), they are replaced exactly as the string given on the macro call, without being expanded
   - otherwise, they are first fully expanded, and only then replaced
2. Stringification and concatenation happen
3. All defined macros are expanded, including macros generated in stringification

**Step-by-step example without indirection**

main.c

```
#define CAT(x) pref_ ## x
#define Y a

CAT(Y)
```

and expand it with:

```
gcc -E main.c
```

we get:

```
pref_Y
```

because:

Step 1: `Y` is a the macro argument of `CAT`.

`x` appears in a stringification `pref_ ## x`. Therefore, `Y` gets pasted as is without expansion giving:

```
pref_ ## Y
```

Step 2: concatenation happens and we are left with:

```
pref_Y
```

Step 3: any further macro replacement happens. But `pref_Y` is not any known macro, so it is left alone.

We can confirm this theory by actually adding a definition to `pref_Y`:

```
#define CAT(x) pref_ ## x
#define Y a
#define pref_Y asdf

CAT(Y)
```

and now the result would be:

```
asdf
```

because on Step 3 above `pref_Y` is now defined as a macro, and therefore expands.

**Step-by-step example with indirection**

If we use the two step pattern however:

```
#define CAT2(x) pref_ ## x
#define CAT(x) CAT2(x)
#define Y a

CAT(Y)
```

we get:

```
pref_a
```

Step 1: `CAT` is evaluated.

`CAT(x)` is defined as `CAT2(x)`, so argument `x` of `CAT` at the definition does not appear in a stringification: the stringification only happens after `CAT2` is expanded, which is not seen in this step.

Therefore, `Y` is fully expanded before being replaced, going through steps 1, 2, and 3, which we omit here because it trivially expands to `a`. So we put `a` in `CAT2(x)` giving:

```
CAT2(a)
```

Step 2: there is no stringification to be done

Step 3: expand all existing macros. We have the macro `CAT2(a)` and so we go on to expand that.

Step 3.1: the argument `x` of `CAT2` appears in a stringification `pref_ ## x`. Therefore, paste the input string `a` as is, giving:

```
pref_ ## a
```

Step 3.2: stringify:

```
pref_a
```

Step 3: expand any further macros. `pref_a` is not any macro, so we are done.

**GCC argument prescan documentation**

GCC's documentation on the matter is also worth a read: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html

**Bonus: how those rules prevent nested calls from going infinite**

Now consider:

```
#define f(x) (x + 1)

f(f(a))
```

which expands to:

```
((a + 1) + 1)
```

instead of going infinite.

Let's break it down:

Step 1: the outer `f` is called with argument `x = f(a)`.

In the definition of `f`, the argument `x` is not part of a concatenation in the definition `(x + 1)` of `f`. Therefore it is first fully expanded before being replaced.

Step 1.1.: we fully expand the argument `x = f(1)` according to steps 1, 2, and 3, giving `x = (a + 1)`.

Now back in Step 1, we take that fully expanded `x` argument equaling `(a + 1)`, and put it inside the definition of `f` giving:

```
((a + 1) + 1)
```

Steps 2 and 3: not much happens, because we have no stringification and no more macros to expand.