# Preprocessor token expansion

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

My mental model of how the preprocessor works is apparently incomplete, and this is driving me crazy.

I want to concatenate two tokens, but the second token should be expanded first.

```
#define ANSWER 42

#define FOO foo_ ## ANSWER
```

Here, `FOO` expands to `foo_ANSWER`, but I want it to be `foo_42`. So I define a `MERGE` macro in the hopes that this would somehow expand the arguments before concatenation:

```
#define MERGE(x, y) x ## y

#define BAR MERGE(bar_, ANSWER)
```

But `BAR` still expands to `bar_ANSWER` instead of `bar_42`. So I define another macro `HELPER`:

```
#define HELPER(x, y) MERGE(x, y)

#define BAZ HELPER(baz_, ANSWER)
```

And now `BAZ` is successfully expanded to `baz_42`. At the moment, this seems like magic to me.

Can anyone explain this behavior to me? How do the expansion rules work exactly?

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I'd also made a possible duplicated question of this same issue. I wonder why don't this behaviour is not documented clearly. I mean the algorithm that preprocessor operates.

Comment: @sandundhammika: Its pretty clearly documented in the spec -- section 6.10.3 -- though there are a number of undefined behavior corners.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read the answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597007/):

> The problem is that when you have a
>   macro replacement, the preprocessor
>   will only expand the macros
>   recursively if neither the stringizing
>   operator # nor the token-pasting
>   operator ## are applied to it. So, you
>   have to use some extra layers of
>   indirection, you can use the
>   token-pasting operator with a
>   recursively expanded argument

Comment: And this is why there is `BOOST_PP_CAT` :)

Comment: The quote above is not correct, or at least not complete.  To expand the macro, you need TWO levels of indirection (tested in VS2017, and reports of the same in Gnu cpp).  I would like to hear an explanation of why the 2nd level of indirection is necessary.  Having just one level indirection, without any "#" or "##", does not expand the macro.  But the 2nd level does.

Answer (score 3):

Token concatenation does not expand macros when performing concatenation [[ref]](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html).

To get past this, you use a level of indirection, and get the preprocessor to expand the macros before the concatenation.

```
#define STEP1(x, y)    STEP2(x, y)    // x and y will be expanded before the call to STEP2
#define STEP2(x, y)    x ## y         // x and y will not be expanded, just pasted
```