# Forming variable name with Macro

Tags: c++, variables, macros

Can I do something like this:

```
#define VERSION 4_1

int32_t myVersion??VERSION;

// What I expect here is that the variable should be generated with name myVersion4_1.
// If possible what should be placed instead of ?? above?
```

Is it possible to form variable name using Macro like above in C++?

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly how you try, but you can do what follows:

```
#define VAR_VERSIONED_NAME(name) name##4_1

int32_t VAR_VERSIONED_NAME(myVersion) = 1;
myVersion4_1 = 2;
```

or if a `VERSION` must be a separate `define`:

```
#define VERSION 4_1

#define CAT_I(a, b) a ## b
#define CAT(a, b) CAT_I(a, b)
#define VAR_VERSIONED_NAME(name) CAT(name, VERSION)

int VAR_VERSIONED_NAME(myVersion) = 1;
myVersion4_1 = 2;
```

Comment: I just want to point out that while this makes the code really flexible, it's very easily overused, which leads to impossible-to-follow code (you basically can't search these variables unless you know they are macro-generated)

Answer (score 1):

You need a level of [indirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284733/preprocessor-token-expansion) to expand `VERSION` before you can paste it.

```
#define VERSION 4_1

#define expand(v) paste(v)
#define paste(v) myVersion ## v

int main()
{
    int expand(VERSION);
    myVersion4_1 = 42;
}
```