# Using a macro to construct a function

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Macro for concatenating two strings in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191316/macro-for-concatenating-two-strings-in-c)

I have a function that looks something like this:

```
bool module_foo_process(void* bar) { return doMagic(bar); }
```

Now, I'd like to generate it with a macro.  For instance, the macro for the above function would look like this:

```
MY_AMAZING_MACRO(foo)
```

This allows me to write something like:

```
MY_AMAZING_MACRO(awesome)
```

and get this:

```
bool module_awesome_process(void* bar) { return doMagic(bar); }
```

Any ideas on how this can be accomplished in C?

Comment: I think you mean token concatenation (##).

Comment: You might like to read here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#define MY_AMAZING_MACRO(name) \
  bool module_##name##_process(void* bar) { return doMagic(bar); }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the concatenation operator `##`:

```
#define MY_AMAZING_MACRO(foo) bool module_##foo##_process(void* bar) { return doMagic(bar); }
```

See the gcc online documentation for more details: [Concatenation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html).