# string concatenation with macro

Tags: c, macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Macro for concatenating two strings in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191316/macro-for-concatenating-two-strings-in-c)

How to concatenate two strings with a macro?

I tried this but it does not give correct results:

```
#define CONCAT(string) "start"##string##"end"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to omit the `##`: [adjacent string literals get concatenated automatically](http://ideone.com/LZBt61), so this macro is going to concatenate the strings the way you want:

```
#define CONCAT(string) "start"string"end"
```

For two strings:

```
#define CONCAT(a, b) (a"" b)
```

Here is a [link to a demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/ycifEk).