# Mixing of two #defines into one word

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

The convention of controls on my dialog is:

```
 #define DLG_NAME              1
 #define DLG_NAME_CONTROL_NAME 2
```

I want to build a function which will know the control name, and has to get the defined value.
It's clear that I can't write `int i = DLG_NAME + _ + CONTROL_NAME`.

So how can I mix the first `#define` and another text to get the second `#define` value?

Comment: Close enough: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503586/what-does-in-a-define-mean?lq=1

Comment: As chris suggested, you can use the `##` operator to combine macro names. However, I do not understand what you want to achieve. Do you want to get `1_2` as an identifier ? (its is not a valid one).

Comment: No. I want the preprocessor will translate `int i = DLG_NAME_CONTROL_NAME`.

Comment: I'll explain better:
I want to create some classes derived from common control class, and I'll write `#define DLG_NAME_FIRST_COMBO 2` and `#define CONTROL_NAME FIRST_COMBO`, and in the class's function I'll write `int i = DLG_NAME##CONTROL_NAME`. Each class will operate it as defined in it. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, what you are looking for is:

```
#define DLG_NAME_FIRST_COMBO 2    
#define CONTROL_NAME(x) DLG_NAME_##x

int i = CONTROL_NAME(FIRST_COMBO);
```

The way you suggested in your comment does not work, since the macro expression is not re-evaluated outside a definition.