# Calling a function name built with __LINE__

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

Suppose, I have built an unique function body from below code:

```
#define TOKENPASTE(x, y) x ## y
#define TOKENPASTE2(x, y) TOKENPASTE(x, y)
#define UNIQUE static void TOKENPASTE2(Unique_, __LINE__)(void)
```

How can I call this function ?

Macro definition taken from: [Creating C macro with ## and __LINE__ (token concatenation with positioning macro)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597007/creating-c-macro-with-and-line-token-concatenation-with-positioning-macro).

Comment: In your edited question.. where you want to call the function ? You can describe more. (Because, you can simply call the function as `Unique_1, Unique_2,...`, if they exist at that line)

Comment: My question is, if a unique function is attempted to defined, but cannot be called, whats the point? @iammilind, how can you call a function in global scope?

Comment: It's correct that you cannot call it so easily. However, you can see my answer, with the help of `template` you have some control to call them.

Answer (score 1):

No. You **cannot**. Because you cannot determine a function name at runtime. (i.e. either to call `Unique_22` or `Unique_44`. However you can definitely call `Unique<22>` or `Unique<44>`)

So you can use `template` solution instead. Declare `Unique` as below:

```
template<unsigned int LINE> void Unique ();
```

And `#define` the macro like this:

```
#define UNIQUE template<> Unique<__LINE__>() {}
```

I advice to use `__COUNTER__` instead of `__LINE__` if your compiler supports it.
[Note: which means that in any line you can call the `UNIQUE` only once and also the macro should be expanded in global or `namespace` scope (not inside a method).]

Comment: The answer to the linked question shows that you can do this with the preprocessor. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597007)

Comment: The edit doesn't seem to make sense; you can't determine a template argument at runtime either (although it could be a compile-time constant; that seems to be the only advantage your version has over the preprocessor version, but I don't see how it's useful to do that).

Comment: @Mike, it may sound vague, but here is what I meant: Suppose at `N`th line, user wants to call the `Unique_N/2` then he cannot call such function using macro solution (i.e. at line `10`, user wants to call `Unique_5`). But with `template` solution one can call as `Unique<N/2>()`.

Answer (score 0):

After replacing the code with the one given in the answer to the SO question you pointed so that it works, ... you can't call this function directly since you can't know for sure its name, that will change if the code change. I have no clue about how this can be useful in code (maybe scanning an object for symbol like `Unique_[0-9]+`? Anyway, it would be an indirect use, in code, as said, you can't use it reliably.