# C preprocessor concatenation outside of #define

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I was wondering *why* we can't use token concatenation outside of `define`s.

This comes up when I want these at the same time:

- conflict-free naming in a library (or for "generics")
- debugability; when using a `define` for this then the whole code gets merged into a line and the debugger will only show the line where the `define` was used

Some people might want an example (*actual question is below that*):

lib.inc:

```
#ifndef NAME
    #error includer should first define NAME
#endif
void NAME() { // works
}
// void NAME##Init() { // doesn't work
// }
```

main.c:

```
#define NAME conflictfree
#include "lib.inc"
int main(void) {
    conflictfree();
    // conflictfreeInit();
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
In file included from main.c:2:0:
lib.h:6:10: error: stray '##' in program
 void NAME##Init();
          ^
```

The rule of thumb is "concat only in define". And if I remember correctly: The reason is because of the preprocessor-phases.
Question: **Why** does it not work. The phases-argument sounds like it was once an implementation-limitation (instead of a logical reason) and then found its way into the standard. What could be so difficult about accepting `NAME##Init()` if `NAME()` works fine?

Comment: Well, the very naive thing would be that the preprocessor directives  are always *starting* with `#`.. I guess the preprocessor devs just lazy to parse the other stuff.

Comment: Probably it could be made to work, if you can convince the C commitee to accept it. But the advantage of `NAME##Init` versus `#define NAME_(x) NAME##x` plus `NAME_(Init)` probably is not worth it.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: But the preprocessor must read _all the code_ to identify and replace when a macro is used. This proposal will just extend that to an adjacent `##`.

Comment: @rodrigo I am not saying it is not possible. But it's like a separate programming language, where it's operators can be processed on the lines marked as written in that language.

Comment: Why would you want to use `##` to change a variable or function name outside of a macro?       What is the advantage of typing  `Foo##Init` over `FooInit`?

Comment: @Peter this is often used in "generic" C libraries. Look at any generic lib and you will see that pattern. The user might write DEF(Foo, int) and DEF(Bar, void*) and get two different functions working on different data types.

Comment: @rodrigo I dont understand your first comment. Could you make a small example?

Comment: @BerndElkemann: See for example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7795770/865874). Not exactly what you want, but near enough.

Comment: I understand that Bernd.   But that happens because of macro expansion.   You're asking to do the same thing without involving a macro, and I don't see the advantage.

Comment: @rodrigo Ah yes, thanks for elaborating.

Comment: In other words, what advantage would there be in typing `void my##func()` to declare a function over `void myfunc()` outside of a macro?   If neither `my` nor `func` are arguments of macros, there is no difference, and there is no genericity.

Comment: Is your proposal that `##` should concatenate two tokens anytime, or only when one or both of them is a preprocessor macro name?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I dont know. You choose.

Comment: I think the closest thing to an answer may be this line from the C standard rationale regarding ##: "These principles codify the essential features of prior 
art and are consistent 
with the specification
of the stringizing operator." The committee tried not to add new features to the language that hadn't already been in wide use; they would sometimes change the syntax to make things less error-prone.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick you should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In section 3.8.3.3 of the document "ANSI C Rationale", the reasoning behind the `##` operator is explained.  One of the basic principles states:

> A formal parameter (or normal operand) as an operand for ## is not expanded before pasting.

This means that you would get the following:

```
#define NAME foo

void NAME##init();   // yields "NAMEinit", not "fooinit"
```

This makes it rather useless in this context, and explains why you have to use two layers of macro to concatenate something stored in a macro.  Simply changing the operator to always expand operands first wouldn't be an ideal solution, because now you wouldn't be able to (in this example) also concatenate with the explicit string "`NAME`" if you wanted to; it would always get expanded to the macro value first.

Answer (score 85):

*Why* was it is not an easy question. Maybe it's time to ask the standard committee why were they as crazy as to standardize (the now removed) `gets()` function as well?

Sometimes, the standard is simply brain-dead, whether we want it or not. The first C was not today's C. It was not "designed" to be today's C, but "grew up" into it. This has led to quite a few inconsistencies and design flaws on the road. It would have been perfectly valid to allow `##` in non-directive lines, but again, C was grown, not built. <sub>And let's not start talking about the consequences that same model brought up into C++...</sub>

Anyway, we're not here to glorify the standards, so one way to get around this follows. First of all, in `lib.inc`...

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef NAME
    #error Includer should first define 'NAME'!
#endif

// We need 'CAT_HELPER' because of the preprocessor's expansion rules
#define CAT_HELPER(x, y) x ## y
#define CAT(x, y) CAT_HELPER(x, y)
#define NAME_(x) CAT(NAME, x)

void NAME(void)
{
    printf("You called %s(), and you should never do that!\n", __func__);

    /************************************************************
     * Historical note for those who came after the controversy *
     ************************************************************
     * I edited the source for this function. It's 100% safe now.
     * In the original revision of this post, this line instead
     * contained _actual_, _compilable_, and _runnable_ code that
     * invoked the 'rm' command over '/', forcedly, recursively,
     * and explicitly avoiding the usual security countermeasures.
     * All of this under the effects of 'sudo'. It was a _bad_ idea,
     * but hopefully I didn't actually harm anyone. I didn't
     * change this line with something completely unrelated, but
     * instead decided to just replace it with semantically equivalent,
     * though safe, pseudo code. I never had malicious intentions.
     */
    recursivelyDeleteRootAsTheSuperuserOrSomethingOfTheLike();
}

void NAME_(Init)(void)
{
    printf("Be warned, you're about to screw it up!\n");
}
```

Then, in `main.c`...

```
#define NAME NeverRunThis
#include "lib.inc"

int main() {
    NeverRunThisInit();
    NeverRunThis();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

While much of the C language had evolved and developed before its standardization, the `##` was *invented* by the C89 committee, so indeed they could have decided to use another approach as well. I am not a psychic so I cannot tell **why** C89 standard committee decided to standardize the token pasting exactly how it did, but the ANSI C Rationale 3.8.3.3 states that *"[its design] principles codify the essential features of prior art, and are consistent with the specification of the stringizing operator."*

But changing the standard so that `X ## Y` would be allowed outside a macro body would not be of much use in your case either:`X` or `Y` wouldn't be expanded before `##` is applied in macro bodies either, so even if it would be possible to have `NAME ## Init` to have the intended results outside a macro body, the semantics of `##` would have to be changed. Were its semantics not changed, you'd still need indirection. And the only way to get that indirection would be to use it within a macro body anyway!

The [C preprocessor already allows you to do what you want to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12630576/918959) (if not exactly with the syntax that you'd want): in your `lib.inc` define the following extra macros:

```
#define CAT(x, y) CAT_(x, y)
#define CAT_(x, y) x ## y
#define NAME_(name) CAT(NAME, name)
```

Then you can use this `NAME_()` macro to concatenate the expansion of `NAME`

```
void NAME_(Init)() {
}
```