# Objective-C How to get the line number where exception was thrown

Tags: objective-c, exception, line

I´m using this in a try - catch structure to get informed in which 
method the exception was thrown:

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
```

I wonder if there is a way in Xcode 4 also to get the line number where the error occurred.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s a `__LINE__` macro that you might find useful, see this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597007/creating-c-macro-with-and-line-token-concatenation-with-positioning-macr) for an inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the `@catch` clause:

```
NSLog(@"Stacktrace: %@", [NSThread callStackSymbols]);
```

During development you can set a symbolic breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw` and see where the error occurs in the Xcode debugger.

Comment: …or [use an exception breakpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961770/run-stop-on-objective-c-exception-in-xcode-4) so you don't have to remember the name `objc_exception_throw`.

Comment: @robmayoff Depends if the want to invoke the debugger before or after the exception is thrown.

Comment: By default, an exception breakpoint breaks on throw (in which case it sets a breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw` for you), but you can change it to break on catch (in which case it sets an exception on `__cxa_begin_catch`).  Maybe I don't understand what you're getting at.

Comment: @robmayoff That's interesting and will save me having to look up `objc_exception_throw` every time I want to catch exceptions :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add an exception break point in the Break Point Navigator menu in the left side of Xcode and this will stop you at the position when the exception happened

Comment: Yes, I´m aware of that. But I´m thinking of a log file where I can see when errors occurred. Not just for debugging during development.