# C preprocessor: concatenation of another define

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm coding for a ARM with GCC and need to concatenate (`##`) a name with the a definition, like this:

```
#define LCD_E_PORT GPIOC 
...
#define RCC_PORT(x) (RCC_APB2Periph_ ## (x)) // ???
...
```

so that after`RCC_PORT(LCD_E_PORT)` I would get `RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOC`. It is important to say, that the `LCD_E_PORT` and the `RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOC` are NOT strings but some low-level system defined pointers (accessing them processor's memory map).

The point of all this is to have one macro, which handles multiple port definitions.

Is there a solution for this?

[image: Removed parantheses]
[image: With parentheses]

I'm using arm-none-eabi-gcc.

Comment: What happens if you try `#define RCC_PORT(x) RCC_APB2Periph_##x` ?

Comment: For example: `RCC_PORT(LCD_E_PORT)` will result in `RCC_APB2Periph_LCD_E_PORT` so it is wrong. I've also tried double definition, I mean: `#define RCC_PORT1(x) RCC_PORT(x)` but after `RCC_PORT1(LCD_E_PORT)` I get an error that `RCC_APB2_Periph_ and "(" don't give a valid token` because, like I said, the GPIOx is a `(u32 *) ptr`. It is that or it doesn't expand macros, or it expands macros to the final definition... All what I need is the definition in the middle.

Answer (score 4):

The kind of thing you need required more indirection through the pre-processor:

This (defines.c) :

```
#define TOKENPASTE( x, y ) x ## y
#define TOKENPASTE2( x, y ) TOKENPASTE( x, y )

#define LCD_E_PORT GPIOC
#define RCC_PORT(x)  TOKENPASTE2( RCC_APB2Periph_, x )

#define STRING(x) #x

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    RCC_PORT(LCD_E_PORT);
}
```

results in the expected output through `gcc -E defines.c` we get:

```
# 1 "defines.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "defines.c"
# 10 "defines.c"
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOC;
}
```

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597007/creating-c-macro-with-and-line-token-concatenation-with-positioning-macr) for more information.