# Concatanate macro argument with another token

Tags: c++, c, macros

I want to create function name inside macro depending on type defined by another macro. For example if I have defined the following macro:

```
#define TYPE int
```

my function name should look like this

```
int_allocate
```

I have tried this:

```
#define CREATE_NAME(VTYPE) VTYPE _allocate
#define FUNCTION_NAME CREATE_NAME(TYPE)
FUNCTION_NAME
```

and got the following line

```
int _allocate
```

as you can see there is one space between **int** and **_allocate**. I know how to concatenate these lines, it should be

```
#define CREATE_NAME(VTYPE) VTYPE ## _allocate
```

but in this case instead of getting **int_allocate** I get **TYPE_allocate**.
When I pass **int** as argument I get correct result

```
#define FUNCTION_NAME CREATE_NAME(int)
```

but I need to pass **macro** as argument

How to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597007/creating-c-macro-with-and-line-token-concatenation-with-positioning-macr

Comment: Thanks Chris it helped a lot