# C++ ## macro doesn't work

Tags: c++, macros

A macro with a `##` will concatenate the two elements together, for example if you use `#define sptember oct ## ober` you will obtain `october`.

So my problem is:
I have a macro like this `#define getRegByPin(pin) set ## pin` than I have from 1 to 19 some defines like this: `#define set0 xxx` and `#define set1 xxx`, etc.

But when I call my macro in code
`int p = getPinNo(pin); st(getRegByPin(p), p, to);` it replaces `getRegByPin(p)` with `setp` instead of `set0` or `set13` or etc.

What can i do?

Thx for help! You are awesome! :)

Comment: short answer: don't use macros.

Comment: if i don't use macros ... what can i use?

Comment: You can use macros, but your example code doesn't make sense.  What is `set0` supposed to be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating C macro with ## and \_\_LINE\_\_ (token concatenation with positioning macro)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597007/creating-c-macro-with-and-line-token-concatenation-with-positioning-macr)

Comment: Why don't you use a function instead of a macro? With inlining and perhaps templates, it should be more type-safe, clean and similarly performant.

Comment: Well, it is working. It just isn't supposed to do what you think it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

The C preprocessor (and C++ has just inherited it), just does textual substitution.  It knows nothing of variables.  So given

```
#define getRegByPin(pin) set ## pin
const int p = 5;

getRegByPin(p);  // Will expand to setp, not set5
```

From the syntax, I guess that `set0` to `set13` are constants.  Do they have values you can calculate?  For example:

```
auto getRegByPin(int pin) { return set0+pin; }  // or (set0 << pin)
```

If not, you are going to need a constant array which you can index:

```
auto getRegByPin(int pin) {
    static const setType_t pins[16] = { set0, set1, set2 ... set15};
    return pins[pin];
}
```

If they are not constants, but functions, your array will need to be an array of function pointers.

Prefer to use functions than the preprocessor.