# Why is the indirection needed

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Consider the following macro:

```
#define CAT(X, Y) X ## Y
#define CMB(A, B) CAT(A, B)
#define SLB_LOGGING_ALGORITHM CMB(Logging, SLB_ALGORITHM)
```

where `SLB_ALGORITHM` is a defined pre-processor symbol.

If I just use `CAT` directly instead of `CMB`, `SLB_ALGORITHM` does not get expanded. Why is that the case and how exactly does the indirection help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1597129/1806873):

> When you have a macro replacement, the preprocessor will only expand the macros recursively if neither the stringizing operator # nor the token-pasting operator ## are applied to it.

So the preprocessor does not expand a given macro when `##` is applied to it. This is why it is exapnded in the `CMB(A, B)` level but not when directly using `CAT(X, Y)` .

Comment: I still don't get how this works exactly. When `CAT` is used directly, the first substitution should produce `CAT(Logging, SLB_ALGORITHM)`, which does not have `##` either...

Comment: When `CAT(Logging, SLB_ALGORITHM)` is used directly `SLB_ALGORITHM` is passed only once to a macro so it translates to `Logging ## SLB_ALGORITHM` which does contain `##`.

Answer (score 5):

`##` is a string concatenator, so if you call `CAT(Logging, SLB_ALGORITHM)` from `SLB_LOGGING_ALGORITHM` macro, this will result in concatenation of string `Logging` with string `SLB_ALGORITHM`, that is: `LoggingSLB_ALGORITHM` which is likely not what you want.

When calling `CMB(Logging, SLB_ALGORITHM)` from `SLB_LOGGING_ALGORITHM` macro, instead, preprocessor first expands `Logging` and `SLB_ALGORITHM` (call to `CMB()`) then concatenate the expanded strings (call to `CAT()`).

Comment: What exactly in the call to `CMB` causes `SLB_ALGORITHM` to get expanded? (more than in the call to `CAT`)