# Stringizing with __FUNCTION__ not working

Tags: c, macros

[Simlar question with **LINE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597007/creating-c-macro-with-and-line-token-concatenation-with-positioning-macr)

But when I replaced `__LINE__` with `__FUNCTION__`.
Macro concat string literal "`__FUNCTION__`" and not actual function name.

Comment: Please ask the actual question you have in *this* question.  Linking to another, putatively similar question does not suffice.  SO questions should stand on their own.

Comment: [C11 `__func__`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.2.2) is not a macro. The preprocessor does not care about it. The same happens with gcc's `__FUNCTION__` extension ( see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html ).

Comment: @pmg any way to stringizing(##) functioname through macro.

Comment: No, not directly. The pre-processor does not have any way to get that information. Unless, of course, you give the information manually... `int fx(void) { #define CURRFUNC "fx" ... } #undef CURRFUNC` ... but, even with this, you can only use CURRFUNC inside the function. *Note that this is a bad idea and I do not reccomend you try anyhting with it*

Comment: `__func__` is already a string, although it is a named array rather than a string literal. What do you want to do with it? It may already be suited for some uses as a string, so there would be no need to stringize it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__FUNCTION__` is not a macro, it's an implicitly declared static array. The same is true for `__func__`, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, etc.

Thus `#` can't work on it. If you want to concatenate something to it, you'll have to do that at runtime, or with `constexpr`.

Comment: I want to it at preprocessor time. Any way?

Comment: @gauravbharadwaj Nope, can't do that. Preprocessor is a simple thing, it doesn't know what functions are.

Comment: @gauravbharadwaj The preprocessor is (at least conceptually) decoupled from the parser and it operates just on directives and token streams. As such it lacks the parsing capability to recognize that after `int (*func(int A, int B))(int C) {`,  `__func__` should expand to `"func"`.

Answer (score 0):

This will keep `__FUNCTION__` as a string macro:

```
#pragma iso_9899_1999
```

Comment: Documentation?  What compiler(s) does this apply to?

Comment: You are right, I just tested it on gcc and it has no impact. I usually use it with clang. As for documentation, I don't know where I found it long ago, sorry. Google does not seem much help.