# the problem about different treatment to __VA_ARGS__ when using VS 2008 and GCC

Tags: visual-studio-2008, gcc

I am trying to identify a problem because of an unusual usage of variadic macros. Here is the hypothetic macro:

```
#define va(c, d, ...) c(d, __VA_ARGS__)
#define var(a, b, ...)  va(__VA_ARGS__, a, b)

var(2, 3, printf, “%d %d %d\n”, 1);
```

For gcc, the preprocessor will output

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", 1, 2, 3)
```

but for VS 2008, the output is

```
printf, “%d %d %d\n”, 1(2, 3);
```

I suspect the difference is caused by the different treatment to **VA_ARGS**, for gcc, it will first expand the expression to va(printf, "%d %d %d\n", 1, 2, 3), and treat 1, 2, 3 as the **VA_ARGS** for macro va. But for VS 2008, it will first treat b as **VA_ARGS** for macro va, and then do the expansion.

Which one is correct interpretation for C99 variadic macro? or my usage falls into an undefined behavior?

Comment: are you trying to actually solve a problem, or are you just performing an academic / research exercise?  There are ways to define the var macro without running into this problem.

Comment: I try to solve the problem. I use this method intensively in my project which saves a lot of time for me: http://liuliu.me/eyes/lets-abusively-use-cpp-macros

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into the ISO/IEC 9899:1999, chapter 6.10.3.1.
It states that:

> **After** the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro have been *identified*, argument substitution takes place. A parameter in the replacement list, unless preceded by a # or ## preprocessing token or followed by a ## preprocessing token (see below), is replaced by the corresponding argument **after** all macros contained therein have been expanded. **Before** being substituted, *each argument’s preprocessing tokens are completely macro replaced* as if they formed the rest of the preprocessing file; no other preprocessing tokens are available.

So in *va* the first argument *c* has one preprocessing token being `__VA_ARGS__`, which, according to this paragraph, must be *macro replaced* before being substituted to *c* (which still does not give the answer as to which compiler is right)

But later:

> An identifier `__VA_ARGS__` that occurs in the replacement list
>   shall be treated as if it were a **parameter**, and the variable
>   arguments shall form the preprocessing tokens used to
>   replace it.

According to the first fragment, first the arguments to *var* are identified. They are: `2`, `3`, `printf`, `“%d %d %d\n”` and `1`. Now argument substitution takes place. This means that parameters from *var*'s replacement list are taken and replaced. However, the second fragment states, that identifier `__VA_ARGS__` is to be treated as a parameter, so it must be substituted to `printf, “%d %d %d\n”, 1`. Now there are no macros inside parameters, so no further substitution takes place, resulting in the expansion of `var(2, 3, printf, “%d %d %d\n”, 1);` into `va(printf, “%d %d %d\n”, 1, 2, 3);`. Because va is a macro, it is also expanded, giving the result of `printf(“%d %d %d\n”, 1, 2, 3);`.
Now if you take VS 2008's reasoning, how can it *identify* the arguments to *va*, if one of them is `__VA_ARGS__` from *var*, and can contain many arguments? Well, it treats `__VA_ARGS__` as an argument to *va*, which in my opition is wrong, as, according to fragment one, argument substitution takes place only *after* the arguments for invocation have been identified.

So it seems to me, that in *var* the preprocessor has to first identify the arguments to the invocation of the macro *va*, and then start expanding *va*. And this means that probably gcc is right here.

It is also shown in [C preprocessor and concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation) how processing tokens are macro-replaced in order, until there are no identifiers which can be further expanded as macros, or the preprocessor spots a recursion and terminates expansion.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Your answer is clear and concise. It seems to me too that gcc's answer makes more sense.

Comment: Well, the fact that gcc's output was more sensible for a normal human being was what I started with, but I hope the answer was not biased. In my opinion the standard should be more precise on the exact order of expanding macros, especially when `__VA_ARGS__` come into play.

Answer (score 6):

There is an easy way to deal with this problem:

```
#define exp(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define va(c, d, ...) c(d, __VA_ARGS__)
#define var(a, b, ...)  exp(va(__VA_ARGS__, a, b))

var(2, 3, printf, “%d %d %d\n”, 1);
```

This will do the trick on VS 2008 and it won't affect gcc