# Swallowing comma in variadic macros on compilers that do not recognise ##

Tags: c, gcc, macros, variadic

I need to write a variadic macro in C which must take zero or more arguments.

In gcc, that can be achieved by adding "##" after the comma, e.g. `,##____VA_ARGS____` as answered in [Variadic macros with zero arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891221/variadic-macros-with-zero-arguments).

However, the compiler in my build system (beyond my control) does not understand the `,##` syntax and so does not swallow the comma.

Is there a workaround I can use?

Comment: Insert a space between , and ## ?

Comment: DipSwitch: Thanks, but I get the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, gcc swallowing the comma is non standard and you should not rely on that.

With C99 conforming preprocessors you may achieve a similar effect by testing for a macro arguments that is the empty token. For the ideas of how this works you could see [here](http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/detect-empty-macro-arguments/), for a whole set of preprocessor macros that ease the programming of such features there is [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr).

Comment: Thanks, though it seems quite a workaound. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Please expand this answer with the actual workaround from the link... or at least how to use P99

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I have provided a simplified version of Jens' blog post.

Answer (score 1):

Using a simplified version what [Jens spelled out](http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/detect-empty-macro-arguments/), a possible approach is described below.

`E_` is used to inject an argument, while `I_` is used to cause indirect invocation of a macro. `V_` is required to add an additional level of indirection, which seems required for [some compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3985071/315052).

```
#define V_(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define I_(M,...) V_(M(__VA_ARGS__))
#define E_() _,
```

Now, suppose you need a macro `MAC` to handle 0, 1, or 2 arguments:

```
MAC(1, 2);
MAC(1);
MAC();
```

One possible implementation might look like:

```
#define MAC_X(_2,_1,X,...) MAC_##X
#define MAC(...) V_(V_(MAC_X(__VA_ARGS__,2,_))(__VA_ARGS__))

#define MAC_2(...) function_for_2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define MAC_1(...) function_for_1(__VA_ARGS__)
#define MAC_0(...) function_for_0(__VA_ARGS__)

#define MAC_Y(_1,Y,...) MAC_##Y
#define MAC__(...) I_(MAC_Y, E_ __VA_ARGS__ () 0, 1)(__VA_ARGS__)
```

And expanding it to 3 arguments is relatively straightforward. The only messiness is detecting 1 or 0 arguments, which does not change:

```
-#define MAC_X(_2,_1,X,...) MAC_##X
-#define MAC(...) V_(V_(MAC_X(__VA_ARGS__,2,_))(__VA_ARGS__))
+#define MAC_X(_3,_2,_1,X,...) MAC_##X
+#define MAC(...) V_(V_(MAC_X(__VA_ARGS__,3,2,_))(__VA_ARGS__))

+#define MAC_3(...) function_for_3(__VA_ARGS__)
 #define MAC_2(...) function_for_2(__VA_ARGS__)
```

---

For more than 1 argument, the `MAC` macro expands into `MAC_2` (or `MAC_3`). But, for 1 or 0 arguments, the `MAC` macro expands to `MAC__`.

The `MAC__` macro applies Jens' trick to detect whether it was passed 1 or 0 arguments. It does this with the `E_` helper macro, and injecting its argument between `E_` and the `()` that would cause it to be invoked. If there are 0 arguments, the `E_` is invoked, and an argument is injected. The injected argument causes `0` to be the second argument for `MAC_Y` to select. If there is 1 argument, `E_` is not expanded. The first argument to the to `MAC_Y` becomes `E_ ... () 0` (where the `...` is whatever the first argument was), and the second argument for `MAC_Y` is `1`. This allows `MAC_Y` to invoke either `MAC_0` or `MAC_1`.