# How to use GCC's printf format attribute with C++11 variadic templates?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, variadic-templates, function-attributes

I have a C++ class that is the frontend for a logging system. Its logging function is implemented using C++11's variadic templates:

```
template <typename... Args>
void Frontend::log(const char *fmt, Args&&... args) {
  backend->true_log(fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Each logging backend implements its own version of `true_log`, that, among other things, uses the forwarded parameters to call `vsnprintf`. E.g.:

```
void Backend::true_log(const char *fmt, ...) {
  // other stuff..
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, fmt);
  vsnprintf(buffer, buffer_length, fmt, ap);
  va_end(ap);
  // other stuff..
}
```

Everything works great, and I am happy.

Now, I want to add a static check on the `log()` parameters: specifically, I would like to use GCC's printf format attribute.

I started by tagging the `log()` function with `__attribute__ ((format (printf, 2, 3)))` (as `this` is the first "hidden" parameter, I need to shift parameter indices by one). This does not work, because if fails with a compilation error:

```
error: args to be formatted is not ‘...’
```

Then, I tried to add the same attribute to the `true_log()` function. It compiles, but no error checking is actually performed: I tried to pass to `log()` some invalid format/variable combinations, and no warning was issued. Maybe this kind of check is "too late", or, in other words, the information about the variable has been lost in the chain of calls?

As a last resort, if I annotated `log()` with `__attribute__ ((format (printf, 2, 0)))`, I would receive warnings about wrong format strings, but no diagnostic would be issued for invalid format/variable combinations.

Summarizing the problem: **how can I have full format checking from GCC if I use C++11's variadic templates?**

Comment: Since vsnprintf() can't deal with more than what old-school ... can do, why bother with variadic templates in the first place?

Comment: Why are you using variadic templates when you're just throwing away the type information? Just make `true_log()` your real logging function.

Comment: Or make `Frontend::log` take a variable argument...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe you can. I bet that GCC only verifies the format string if it's a *literal*. This is why putting the `format` attribute on `true_log` doesn't work - that function is called with what looks (syntactically) like a runtime-determined string. Putting it on `log` directly would circumvent that, but would require `format` attributes to support variadic template, which you proved it doesn't.

I suggest that you look at more C++-ish ways to do formatted output. There is, for example, `boost::format` which works kind of like printf, but dynamically verifies that the number and types of the parameters types match the format string. It doesn't use variadic templates, though, but instead consumes parameters fed to it (via operator %) one-by-one.

Answer (score 5):

For the record, I ended up removing the C++11 variadic templates altogether, and using a traditional `va_list`.

```
__attribute__((format(printf, 2, 3)))
void Frontend::log(const char *fmt, ...) {
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, fmt);
  backend->true_log(fmt, ap);
  va_end(ap);
}

void Backend::true_log(const char *fmt, va_list ap) {
  // log the message somehow
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a workaround if you are willing to use a macro.

There are constructs that will cause the compiler to do the checking for you, but will not generate any called code. One such construct is `sizeof`. So, you could use a macro for your logger to pass the arguments to `printf` directly but in the context of a `sizeof` calculation, and then call the logger itself.

The reason to use a macro is to make sure the format string is treated just like a string literal would be treated.

In the illustration below, I treat the `sizeof` calculation as a throwaway argument, but there should be other ways to apply the same technique.

```
template <typename... Ts>
void Frontend::log(size_t, const char *fmt, Ts&&... args) {
  backend->true_log(fmt, std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}

#define log(...) log(sizeof(printf(__VA_ARGS__)), __VA_ARGS__)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVFNT4MwGL7zK95scaGGkXiFhWQe9K6LXkyaWlrWDNradjNz2V8XS0FQ4zgA78fz0adU62VFaTsXktb7ksGqYY0yxyKaOtaVQqXbPy1iKt9rrTN76uCW0B2TJZwi8M9BiRL8gOFaVTFV0jqgW2LgOoE0TVEenfMoGqB3Rkk3YR1rdE2cF3FHzSRpmEfAxhYTc0dqxQfDLoHf5Bu7WPQC3bJ3mWV7Kd68Ee3MajBZwGv/02@N@jGC7HsUB2xDdgz3BCM4RghO53CAy1aDzW/iLLtkmDdu9Aw@UItCCIOHZTFGGBaDJa7MOzHlyqvEATHkGUXzknEhWUina44xKR5rI6TjMcZPa7x@uH/EGKEEfpZR73k4ZZb9e3vBRuDubB4IroWfEZ33lXXEuJjoBPxiuIPDIByARKNhsQs4VOfWj6EhQnbpn6a74DnwtJOfXdkXOUvgBuVwbj8pr0ll2@UzM0YZ/yV17d9f)

Of course, this is a workaround. There are numerous reasons not to use a macro. And in this case, the `log` macro would interfere with any other function or method with the same name.

Comment: Please note that forwarding `__VA_ARGS__ ` you should use `##__VA_ARGS__`
Other than that I really like this solution.

Comment: Also you should probably change the macro to something like this:
`#define log(f, ...) true_log(sizeof(printf(f,##__VA_ARGS__)), f, ##__VA_ARGS)`

Comment: @SebastianCabot: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8444698/315052

Comment: @SebastianCabot: So, since the format string is a required argument, I don't need to use the non-standard comma swallowing operator.

Comment: Good points! Thank you very much for pointing them out