# function with function object argument of different signatures

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind, boost-function, boost-signals

I tried overloading a function with boost::function with different signatures, it did not work.
I tried using `template<Signature> Connection *connect(boost::function<Signature> f)` which also failed because boost::bind doesn't implicitly convert that way

What I'm trying to do is exactly what boost::signals does. Boost signals can accept both, function object without arguments and function objects with N arguments

I want to know how I can accept both type of function objects in one function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use variadic templates:

```
template<typename R, typename... Args>
Connection* connect(boost::function<R (Args...)> f);
```

This will accept both a function that takes 0 arguments or one that accepts N arguments.

Comment: I tried that, however, I got a compile error "ServerSignal(70): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '...'". Maybe my compiler is not up to date? I am using Visual Studio 2012. Is there any other way? I would like to use a more backward compatible method. Any idea how boost does it? I am using 2 function objects, one with arguments and other without. I need to use the correct connect method to decide which function object to use.

Comment: @SaifUrRehman Visual Studio 2012 doesn't support variadic templates unfortunately, and I'm not sure how boost does it. My only suggestion would be to use function overloading on `function<R (Arg)>` and `function<R ()>`.

Comment: @SaifUrRehman I think the answer to this question might give you some help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237350/using-variadic-macros-or-templates-to-implement-a-set-of-functions

Comment: @SaifUrRehman Another thing to do would be to implement a type list which is relatively simple. Here is the source code to the type lists shown in Modern C++ Design -- http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00681.html