# Function Definition Generation from Declaration using Template Metapogramming

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, variadic-macros

C++ gurus,

I have a template metaprogramming question. Consider the following
function declaration.

```
int foo(const int x[], char *y, size_t size);
```

I would like to be able to generate the function body as follows:

```
int foo(const int x[], char *y, size_t size)
{
  return myfnc(x, y, size);
}
```

Is there a way to do this with C++ template metaprogramming?  I can
"wrap" the declaration in some macro, but I'd like to avoid the use
of macros to do the full expansion. For example, I'd be happy if
I can write something along the lines of:

```
DEFINE_FNC(foo, const int x[], char *y, size_t size)
```

where `DEFINE_FNC` is defined as

```
#define DEFINE_FNC(fnc, ...) \
int fnc(__VA_ARGS__) {       \
  return myfnc(__VA_ARGS__); \ // This doesn't work; is there something else that can be done here?
}                            \
```

I'm aware of the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237350/using-variadic-macros-or-templates-to-implement-a-set-of-functions/18296062#18296062), but that requires me
to add parenthesis around the parameter types, and I'd like to
avoid that, if possible.

I tried to use variadic templates, but it doesn't do the exact thing
I want.

Comment: An XY problem? Explain what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: "that requires me to add parenthesis around the parameter types," ...how else do you expect the preprocessor to get at the `x` in `const int x []`?  (In C++, you really should prefer the variadic template approach anyway).

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename Args...>
int foo(Args&&... args) {
  return myfnc(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

You can have a macro stamping out such definitions, if you are so inclined.