# Cross-platform macro wrapper for fprintf()

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

Is there a cross-platform approach to wrapping `fprintf()` so I that I can have a simple logging function for dumping logs to either files or the console, and utilizes a simple C `printf()` style format string and arguments list?

Right now, I'm doing something like so:

```
#define logIssue(fmt, ...) do { \
    fprintf(stderr, "MY_PREFIX:%s:%s:%d > " fmt "\n", __FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
} while(0);
```

This works in GCC, and if I remove the leading `##`, it works in GCC **and** Visual Studio 2005 (yes, I have to have this working on VS2005 through 2015), but it fails in Visual Studio versions prior to 2012 when I don't actually have a variable arguments list, ie:

```
logIssue("Problem with test#%d.", iTestID); // Succeeds
logIssue("General problem."); // Fails
```

I've read into this issue at length, including the following:

- [Standard alternative to GCC's ##**VA_ARGS** trick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588855/standard-alternative-to-gccs-va-args-trick)
- [MSVC doesn't expand **VA_ARGS** correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134523/msvc-doesnt-expand-va-args-correctly)
- [the problem about different treatment to **VA_ARGS** when using VS 2008 and GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575864/the-problem-about-different-treatment-to-va-args-when-using-vs-2008-and-gcc)

These offer potential solutions, but I can't seem to integrate them with my `fprintf()` macro.

Is there any straightforward way to have this wrapper macro work in Linux (GCC) and Windows (MSVC 2005 and onward) via macro tricks?

Thank you.

Comment: How much of C99 can you use?

Comment: @FUZxxl Since I have to support VS2005 through 2015, I can't really depend on C99. At least for GCC, my constraints are much more relaxed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for extensions:

```
#define logIssue(...) do {      
    fprintf(stderr, "MY_PREFIX:%s:%s:%d > ", __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__ );
    fputs( "", stderr);
} while(0)
```

This works with both calls, and is C99 compliant:

```
logIssue("Problem with test#%d.", iTestID);
logIssue("General problem.");
```

Comment: Thank you. I swapped the final `fputs` call with `fprintf(stderr, "\n")` and I'm all set. :)