# GCC Preprocessor for inline method name

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, stringification

I'm working on a project where I have code like the following:

```
#define NAME() Array

inline NAME()* NAME()_init (void* arg0){return (NAME()*)Object_init(arg0);}
```

But I get the following result:

```
inline Array* Array _init (void* arg0){return (Array*)Object_init(arg0);}
```

With a space between the "Array" and the "_init"
Because this is a function name, I obviously do not want the space. Does anyone know how to get the space out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the semantics in something like this:

```
#define NAME(X) Array##X
inline NAME()* NAME(_init) (void* arg0){return (NAME()*)Object_init(arg0);}
```

**EDIT**: At least it works with GNU cpp.

**EDIT2**: tried also with `-ansi -pedantic` and it seemed to work without warning...

Comment: it could be, but the OP specified GNU preprocessor, and I've tested with it

Comment: Sorry; my mistake.  C99 added support for empty arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to combine two tokens into one (e.g., to combine the result of invoking `NAME()` and `_init`) is to use the concatenation operator (`##`).  You'll need to do something like so:

```
#define REAL_CONCATENATE(x, y) x ## y
#define CONCATENATE(x, y) REAL_CONCATENATE(x, y)

#define NAME() Array
inline NAME()* CONCATENATE(NAME(), _init) (void* arg0){return (NAME()*)Object_init(arg0);}
```

Yes, [the extra level of indirection is necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation/1489985#1489985).

Note that you don't need to use a function-like macro if you take no parameters, so you could just as easily use:

```
#define NAME Array
inline NAME* CONCATENATE(NAME, _init) (void* arg0){return (NAME*)Object_init(arg0);}
```

Comment: It's called token pasting rather that concatenation - string concatenation occurs after tokenisation, pasting before, and doesn't require any operator.

Comment: @Pete:  Both the C and C++ language standards use the word _concatenate;_ that doesn't mean that _token concatenation_ is the same thing as _string literal concatenation_ (or any other form of concatenation, for that matter).