# How to force processor to use result of expression before pasting

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, boost-preprocessor

My code is

```
#define PASTE__(a, b) a##b
#define PASTE_(a, b)  PASTE__(a, b)
#define PASTE(a, b) PASTE_(a, b)

int main()
{
    PASTE(1, (1+3)/4);
    return 0;
}
```

I would LIKE to have the result be

```
int main()
{
    11;
    return 0;
}
```

Compilable link: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b35ea3e35a1b56ae

I put in two levels of indirection suggested by [How can I guarantee full macro expansion of a parameter before paste?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221896/how-can-i-guarantee-full-macro-expansion-of-a-parameter-before-paste).

But still I get a preprocessor error:

```
main.c:8:11: error: pasting "1" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
     PASTE(1, (1+3)/4);
           ^
main.c:1:23: note: in definition of macro 'PASTE__'
 #define PASTE__(a, b) a##b
                       ^
main.c:3:21: note: in expansion of macro 'PASTE_'
 #define PASTE(a, b) PASTE_(a, b)
                     ^
main.c:8:5: note: in expansion of macro 'PASTE'
     PASTE(1, (1+3)/4);
```

How do I get the preprocessor to resolve the result of that expression before doing concatenation?

Comment: The preprocessor does not concern itself with evaluation, it only pastes.

Comment: But it evaluates things like #if 3 < 2.

Comment: The code appears not to be C, but C++. These are different languages, pick one!

Comment: News: a macro is different from a conditional preprocessor statement or a comment.

Comment: Succinctly: you don't (get the preprocessor to resolve the result of that expression before doing concatenation).

Comment: Token pasting can only combine two tokens to form another token. The formed token must meet the definition of a token.  `1(` is NOT a token (that would be two tokens).  A working example would be pasting `a` and `b` to get `ab`, which is a single token.

Comment: Please update your question to include the result you are expecting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to get the preprocessor to evaluate some simple mathematical operations and convert to the result.  This is not possible without substantial extra macro infrastructure to perform the necessary math.  The easiest way to get the needed infrastructure is probably to use BOOST_PP.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html

You would need to modify your code so that macros are used to perform the math rather than operators.  The line in question would look like:

```
PASTE(1, BOOST_PP_DIV(BOOST_PP_ADD(1,3),4));
```

Now the answer would come out as 11, and I assume that's what you're looking for.

Comment: If I were using C++, it'd definitely be useful.

Comment: "The Boost Preprocessing library is a library of macros, with support for preprocessor metaprogramming. **The library supports both C++ and C compilation. It does not depend on any other Boost libraries and therefore may be used as a standalone library**" - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html

Comment: I have tested this in a C program and it works perfectly.

Comment: I switched the "answer" @MichaelBurr

Answer (score 0):

What *exactly* are you hoping the preprocessor output for the `PASTE` line will be?  `11;`?  That's impossible.  (update: apparently it *is* possible with clever enough macros.  See Charles Ofria's answer).

That double-expansion with multiple macros is only useful for expanding macros and then stringifying the results, IIRC.

Comment: @Adrian: turns out I was wrong, and this is possible.  You should mark Charles's answer as correct.

Comment: Ok I did. But still gave you upvote because in my case, using Boost won't be accepted by peers - embedded in automotive industry - so knowing that preprocessor doesn't evaluate expression DIRECTLY is still useful information. I'm gonna use Python to pre-preprocess my .c files.

Comment: @Adrian: As long as you only use pre-processor boost library, and not any other part of Boost, it can't bloat your code (unless you use it to generate bloated code, which this case doesn't do).  After pre-processing, the compiler will still see an `11`.  If you can't add a dependency on the Boost header, then sure, work around it.

Comment: Oh I know it won't bloat it. But you've never worked in automotive: if I say 'I got it from the internet' everyone freaks.

Comment: I've reimplimented basic macro math from scratch if you want a set of macros with an explanation for how they work.  Then you can just say you got it from a Professor of Computer Science at Michigan State.  ;-)