# How Can I use double Macro in C

Tags: c, macros, precompile

Let's see my code T.T

I defined my macros as shown as below

This is my macro header file. macro.h

```
#define BUZZER_PWM                                  PWMA
#define BUZZER_PWM_CH                               0
#define ENABLE_PWM(pwm,ch)      (pwm)->POE |= PWM_POE_PWM##ch##_Msk
```

and call macro in another cfile

```
ENABLE_PWM(BUZZER_PWM,BUZZER_PWM_CH);
```

I pretected the result after precompile is

```
PWMA -> POE |= PWM_POE_PWM0_Msk;
```

But

```
PWMA -> POE |= PWM_POEBUZZER_PWM_CH_Msk;
```

is resulted.
Is there any solution??

Sorry for my ugly English skills..

Comment: Essentially duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3221914/10404680).

Comment: when writing header files, always include the include guards: at the top of the file: `#ifndef MACRO_H` and `#define MACRO_H`  then at the end of the file: `#endif // MACRO_H`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure the macro arguments (specifically `BUZZER_PWM_CH` in your case) get expanded before the concatenation (`PWM_POE_PWM##ch##_Msk`) use an additional macro.

Example file `macro.c`

```
#define BUZZER_PWM                                  PWMA
#define BUZZER_PWM_CH                               0
#define ENABLE_PWM(pwm,ch)      ENABLE_PWM_(pwm,ch)
#define ENABLE_PWM_(pwm,ch)      (pwm)->POE |= PWM_POE_PWM##ch##_Msk     

/* expected expansion */
ENABLE_PWM(BUZZER_PWM,BUZZER_PWM_CH);

/* wrong expansion */
ENABLE_PWM_(BUZZER_PWM,BUZZER_PWM_CH);
```

is expanded as

```
$ gcc -E macro.c
# 1 "macro.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 31 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 32 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "macro.c"






(PWMA)->POE |= PWM_POE_PWM0_Msk;


(PWMA)->POE |= PWM_POE_PWMBUZZER_PWM_CH_Msk;
```