# Argument Preceded by a # Token in a Macro

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, stringification

```
#define LINK_ENTITY_TO_CLASS(mapClassName,DLLClassName) \
    static CEntityFactory<DLLClassName> mapClassName( #mapClassName );
```

This is a macro from the Alien Swarm mod for Half-Life 2, meant to be compiled with MSVC.

I've never seen an argument preceded by a `#` in a macro before, and I'm not sure if this is a MSVC specific thing or just uncommon. What does it mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is part of both standard C and C++ and is not implementation-specific.  The `#` preprocessing operator stringizes its argument.  It takes whatever tokens were passed into the macro for the parameter designated by its operand (in this case, the parameter `mapClassName`) and makes a string literal out of them.  So, for a simple example,

```
#define STRINGIZE(x) # x

STRINGIZE(Hello World)
// gets replaced with
"Hello World"
```

Note that the argument tokens are *not* macro replaced before they are stringized, so if `Hello` or `World` were defined as a macro, the result would still be the same.  You need to [use an extra level of indirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation/1489985#1489985) to get the arguments macro replaced (that linked answer discusses the concatenation operator, `##`, but applies equally to the stringization operator.

Comment: Your answer is right, but I just want to clarify this is a standard part of C preprocessor, and not a MSVC specific thing.

Comment: @Swiss:  Sorry; yes:  this is a part of the C language standard.