# Weird C++ preprocessor macro syntax

Tags: c++, concatenation, c-preprocessor

I've distilled my problem down to this code snippet - but it is a part of a larger program so I don't want a different way to do this - I need a way to make *this* work!

When I generate a preprocessed file from this code:

```
#define OUTER(a, b) \
    a##b
#define INNER(c, d) \
    c##d

enum foo {
    OUTER(INNER(x, y), z)
}; // line 108

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(...)
{
    foo bar = xyz; // line 112
}
```

I get:

```
enum foo {
    xyz
}; // line 108

int __stdcall wWinMain(...)
{
    foo bar = xyz; // line 112
}
```

which is what I want. However, if I try to compile the code I get:

> error C2146: syntax error : missing '}' before identifier 'z' line 108
>       error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}' line 108
>       error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}' line 108
>       error C2059: syntax error : '}' line 108
>       error C2065: 'xyz' : undeclared identifier line 112

I can't work it out! The problem seems to be caused by the `##` in the:

```
#define OUTER(a, b) \
    a##b
```

but why (and how to fix it) is beyond me...

Comment: @Jack Could you explain what a##b is supposed to do? Never saw this before.

Comment: @Insert It's a preprocessor operator that literally concatenates its two arguments.  For instance, `OUTER(test, string)` in the OP code snippet is replaced by `teststring` by the preprocessor.

Comment: OK well I can confirm that this happens in gcc too, and their error is a bit more descriptive. It's saying that it can't paste `)` and `z` together. It looks to me like the preprocessor can't do nested pastes like this, but this is guesswork at this point. Hope that helps a bit..

Comment: @InsertNickHere:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09dwwt6y%28VS.80%29.aspx  It is the Token-Pasting Operator

Comment: @InsertNickHere It's token concatenation, part of any C preprocessor. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation

Comment: Can you provide a more realistic example of usage or the macros?  Right now, the macros are essentially useless.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
#define CONCAT(X,Y) X##Y
#define OUTER(a, b) CONCAT(a,b)
#define INNER(a, b) CONCAT(a,b)

enum foo {
    OUTER(INNER(x, y),z)
}; // line 108

int main(...)
{
    foo bar = xyz; // line 112
}
```

Comment: Woo hoo it works! But can you explain to me why it works? Why is my preprocessed output correct? I see from the gcc error described below that it appears to be keeping a ")" and trying to concatenate the "z" to "xy)"? But this doesn't appear in my preprocessed output!

Comment: Read Jonathan Leffler's canonical answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation

Comment: Ah! Is OUTER getting "INNER(c, d), z" and not "xy, z" as I thought? That would make sense. But I still don't get why my preprocessed output is correct!

Comment: No need to declare two separate OUTER/INNER macros, this works also:
OUTER(OUTER(x, y),z)

Answer (score 2):

Preprocessing your example with `gcc` results in:

```
enum foo {
t.c:7:1: error: pasting ")" and "z" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    xy z
};
```

which should give you a clue of why Luther's solution works and yours doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gcc, then you can give it the -E option to see the preprocessed output.  Then you can easily see what the preprocessor has output and how to further debug your macros.  Other compilers also have similar options.