# C preprocessor magic

Tags: c, visual-studio, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to use preprocessor tricks to declare a magic variable. Something like this:

```
DECLARE(x)
```

should expand to

```
int _DECLARED_VARIABLE_x_LINE_12
```

if the declaration was on line 12 of the input source. I was trying to use the ## token-pasting command and the `__LINE__` macro, but I either get an uninterpreted "`__LINE__`" in there or the preprocessor seems to completely ignore my line. My current guess is:

```
 #define DECLARE(x) _DECLARED_VARIABLE_ ## x ## _LINE_ ## __LINE__
```

Comment: you should use backticks or backslashes to escape your underscores, or markdown will make them disappear

Comment: Remove the initial underscore or your program has undefined behavior.

Comment: How can you refer the magic variables? Just curious.

Comment: @Praveen, identifiers that begin with an underscore and a capital letter are reserved. Using any that are known to exist in your implementation is fine. Declaring your own is not so fine.

Comment: @RBerteig : I understand that point, what i am unclear is, if a variable is declared as above with the line number as its unique val, how can you access them in other part of the code.

Comment: @Praveen, now that is a real mystery. Of course, it could be useful for names that you don't want to ever use again...

Comment: @RBerteig -  I don't understand the use of variables which we would not use except for generating gcc warning for unused variables. I wish we were enlightened here. What say you? :-)

Comment: @Praveen, here's one use case I actually use: creating a compile-time assertion by a macro that expands to something like `typedef int some_name[ (condition) ? 1 : -1 ];` where the typedef can be compiled if the condition is true, but generates an error if false. I don't care what the actual type name is, because I am only using it to generate an error. On the other hand, it has to have a unique name so that it can appear more than once in a file.

Comment: ... you need tricks to do this so that you can write assertions based on `sizeof` that are tested during compilation. Unfortunately, `sizeof` is not known to the preprocessor so an ordinary `#if` can't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C preprocessor and concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The normal trick in such cases is to use a second macro.  However, that does not seem to work with GCC (4.5.1 on MacOS X 10.6.4), and a third level of macro was needed:

```
#define DECLARE(x) _DECLARED_VARIABLE_ ## x ## _LINE_ ## __LINE__

#define DECLARE42(x, line) _DECLARED_VARIABLE_ ## x ## _LINE_ ## line
#define DECLARE41(x, line) DECLARE42(x, line)
#define DECLARE40(x) DECLARE41(x, __LINE__)

int DECLARE(y);
int DECLARE40(c) = 129;
```

Output of 'gcc -E':

```
# 1 "magicvars.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "magicvars.c"






int _DECLARED_VARIABLE_y_LINE___LINE__;
int _DECLARED_VARIABLE_c_LINE_8 = 129;
```

I'm not sure I have a good explanation of why the third level of macro was needed.

I am also curious to know how you are ever going to refer to these variables after you've created them.

---

I went through a number of variations before managing to hit on the one that worked:

```
#define DECLARE(x) _DECLARED_VARIABLE_ ## x ## _LINE_ ## __LINE__

#define DECLARE11(x, line) _DECLARED_VARIABLE_ ## x ## _LINE_ ## line
#define DECLARE10(x) DECLARE11(x, __LINE__)

#define DECLARE23(line) _LINE_ ## line
#define DECLARE22(x) _DECLARED_VARIABLE_ ## x
#define DECLARE21(x, line) DECLARE22(x) ## DECLARE23(line)
#define DECLARE20(x) DECLARE21(x, __LINE__)

#define DECLARE32(line) _LINE_ ## line
#define DECLARE31(x, line) _DECLARED_VARIABLE_ ## x ## DECLARE32(line)
#define DECLARE30(x) DECLARE31(x, __LINE__)

#define DECLARE42(x, line) _DECLARED_VARIABLE_ ## x ## _LINE_ ## line
#define DECLARE41(x, line) DECLARE42(x, line)
#define DECLARE40(x) DECLARE41(x, __LINE__)


int DECLARE(y);
int DECLARE10(z) = 12;
int DECLARE20(a) = 37;
int DECLARE30(b) = 91;
int DECLARE40(c) = 129;
```

Have fun working out why the non-working ones didn't work.  They did, however, point me towards the working answer.  (I note that the Sun C compiler produces essentially the same results as GCC on the same input.)

Comment: to answer your other question, I'm not going to refer to those variables in the code; I need this for some compiler tools I'm tinkering with.

Answer (score 7):

The preprocessor removes the `##` operators from the macro replacement list *before* attempting to look for further macros for recursive replacement. This means that your reference to `__LINE__` gets "glued" to the rest of the macro *before* it has a chance to get recognized as `__LINE__` and replaced with the actual line number.

For this reason, if you want to embed the line number into your macro, you have no other choice but to pass it through a macro parameter

```
#define DECLARE_(x, L) _DECLARED_VARIABLE_##x##_LINE_##L
#define DECLARE(x) DECLARE_(x, __LINE__)
```

And that will formally solve the immediate problem in your original macro definition.

However, this still will not work as expected due to another quirk in C/C++ preprocessor specification: parameter names adjacent to `##` are replaced with the corresponding arguments values *without* the recursive macro expansion in the argument value. I.e. `L` will be replaced with `__LINE__`, without changing `__LINE__` to the actual line number first.

To ensure the recursive macro expansion for parameter `L`, one needs to introduce another "level of indirection" in macro definition

```
#define DECLARE__(x, L) _DECLARED_VARIABLE_##x##_LINE_##L
#define DECLARE_(x, L) DECLARE__(x, L)
#define DECLARE(x) DECLARE_(x, __LINE__)
```

In this case, when processing `DECLARE_(x, L)` macro, the preprocessor will handle `L` recursively: first replace it with `__LINE__` and then replace `__LINE__` with the actual line number. `DECLARE__` will receive the complete line number.

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with `__LINE__` in debug mode with Visual Studio if you were using Edit and Continue. [Here is a reference to it.](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/375836/-line-not-seen-as-compile-time-constant)  That issue is a few years old though.  If that issue is resolved, then [Jonathan Leffler's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580533/c-preprocessor-magic/3580744#3580744) will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are two special expansion rules regarding ## operator:

1. Operands to ## operator are not expanded before pasting.
2. Macro arguments are not expanded if they are concatenated with ##.