# What is the use of ## preprocessor in C

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C preprocessor and concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation)

can anybody explain with example ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It allows to construct indentifiers from their parts. Eg:

```
#define CLASS_NAME(name) CLASS__ ## name
```

would expand `CLASS_NAME(alpha)` to `CLASS__alpha`. It is vastly used in tricks used by the boost preprocessor library, eg.

```
#define IF0(a, b) b
#define IF1(a, b) a
#define IF(cond, a, b) IF ## cond(a, b)
```

which would expand `IF(0, a, b)` to `a` and `IF(1, a, b)` to `b`. Also, sometimes, it is used to generate struct and function names (akin to c++ templates).

Comment: Isn't IF(0, a, b) mapped to b and IF(1, a, b) mapped to a?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you meen by "##" preprocessor.

C has a preprocessor for expanding macros *before* compile time. This is a first pass on the source code. There are a few different things it is used for:

- including other source / header files (`#include`)
- conditionally compiling code (`#ifdef` etc.)
- expanding macros (`#define`)

  - handy for constants
  - simple functions

Note, though, that this is not really "C" (though part of the spec) and can cause headaches if you get it wrong. I believe new languages would not do it this way anymore.

Comment: Hi Daren jpalecek's answer is what i was expecting. Thanks for the heads up.