# What does a double hash (##) in a macro mean?

Tags: c++, c

In the below code, what does the `##` do?

```
 #define MAKE_TYPE(myname) \
 typedef int myname ## Id; \
```

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [SO 1489932 C Preprocessor and Concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation/)

Answer (score 22):

The `##` in a macro is concatenation. Here, `MAKE_TYPE(test)` will expand to : `typedef int testId`.

From 16.3.3 (The ## operator) :

> For both object-like and function-like
>   macro invocations, before the
>   replacement list is reexamined for
>   more macro names to replace, each
>   instance of a ## preprocessing token
>   in the replacement list (not from an
>   argument) is deleted and the preceding
>   preprocessing token is concatenated
>   with the following preprocessing token

Comment: I would underline the *before the replacement list is reexamined*. If you write `MAKE_TYPE(OBJECT(Foo))` then you will have `typedef int OBJECT(Foo)Id;`... which is obviously invalid. Dealing with macros is... complicated, and best avoided especially for such trivial cases where it only obfuscate things.

Answer (score 5):

icecrime is correct, but something important to point out in the definition is that the tokens need to be valid preprocessing tokens. Examples:

```
#define CONCAT(a,b) a ## b
CONCAT(ClassyClass, <int>); // bad, <int> is not a valid preprocessing token
CONCAT(Symbol, __LINE__); // valid as both are valid tokens
```

Comment: That caused me a great deal of frustration several years ago, as I wanted to concatenate three things together, and the combination of neither the first nor the last pair were valid preprocessing tokens.

Comment: Great point, but not an answer. Should've been a comment to icecrime's.