# "Define" Macro Concatenation and _TEXT

Tags: c++

is there any way of concatenation #define macros in c++ (ms compiler)?

I have existing code like this:

```
#define LOG_FILENAME _TEXT("VendorBlaBlaDriver.log")
#define REGISTRY_FILENAME _TEXT("VendorBlaBlaDriver")
#define VENDOR_NAME _TEXT("VendorBlaBla")
```

I wanna do the following:

```
#define NAME_PART1 "VenorBlaBla"
#define NAME_PART2 "Driver"

#define LOG_FILENAME _TEXT(NAME_PART1 NAME_PART2 ".log")
#define REGISTRY_FILENAME _TEXT(NAME_PART1 NAME_PART2)
#define VENDOR_NAME _TEXT(NAME_PART1)
```

But compiler gives me an error:

```
error C2308: concatenating mismatched strings
```

Is there any way of doing this right? The thing is that's a component and I want to specify -D option to compiler later. I don't want to store NAME_PART1 and NAME_PART2 in source code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C preprocessor and concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation)

Comment: no, there is no _TEXT macros there

Comment: You can simply type #define LOG_FILENAME NAME_PART1 NAME_PART2 ".log" or am I missing something?

Comment: Hint: If you follow the advice and use `_TEXT` multiple times, you can use the short `_T` macro, that expands to the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't apply the `_TEXT` macro twice. or on multiple strings, but you can concatenate the results. I.e.

```
#define LOG_FILENAME _TEXT(NAME_PART1) _TEXT(NAME_PART2) _TEXT(".log")
```

However, you really shouldn't bother. The `_TEXT` macro was used around the turn of the century, when there were still non-Unicode platforms around. Today we just write `#define NAME_PART1 L"VenorBlaBla"` ; nobody is selling Windows 95 software anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the _TEXT is being applied to NAME_PART1 only, and not the other parts, this should be written as:

```
#define NAME_PART1 "VenorBlaBla"
#define NAME_PART2 "Driver"

#define LOG_FILENAME      _TEXT(NAME_PART1) _TEXT(NAME_PART2) _TEXT(".log")
#define REGISTRY_FILENAME _TEXT(NAME_PART1) _TEXT(NAME_PART2)
#define VENDOR_NAME       _TEXT(NAME_PART1)
```

The mismatch is _TEXT is defining a wide-string, where as the other strings are still normal strings.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this work (not got a compiler to hand yet to try it out):

```
#define LOG_FILENAME _TEXT(NAME_PART1) _TEXT(NAME_PART2) _TEXT(".log")
```

and then let the compiler concatenate the two strings.