# How to concatenate strings with C preprocessor with dots in them?

Tags: c, concatenation, c-preprocessor

I've read the following question and the answer seems clear enough:
[How to concatenate twice with the C preprocessor and expand a macro as in "arg ## _ ## MACRO"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation)

But what if VARIABLE has a dot at the end?

I'm trying to do a simple macro that increments counters in a struct for debugging purposes. I can easily do this even without the help from the above question simply with

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DEBUG_INC_COUNTER(x) x++
#endif
```

and call it

```
DEBUG_INC_COUNT(debugObj.var1);
```

But adding "debugObj." to every macro seems awfully redundant. However if I try to concatenate:

```
#define VARIABLE debugObj.
#define PASTER(x,y) x ## y++
#define EVALUATOR(x,y)  PASTER(x,y)
#define DEBUG_INC_COUNTER(x) EVALUATOR(VARIABLE, x)
DEBUG_INC_COUNTER(var)

gcc -E macro.c
```

I get

```
macro.c:6:1: error: pasting "." and "var" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

So how should I change this so that

```
DEBUG_INC_COUNTER(var);
```

generates

```
debugObj.var++;
```

?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Omit the `##`; this is only necessary if you want to join strings. Since the arguments aren't strings, the spaces between them don't matter (`debugObj    . var1` is the same as `debugObj.var1`).

Comment: D'oh! I got too clever there.

Answer (score 8):

You should not paste them together using `##`, as you can have `debugObj` `.`, and `var1` as separate preprocessor tokens.

The following should work:

```
#define DEBUG_INC_COUNTER(x) debugObj.x++
```

Comment: Your edit cleared your answer, Aaron's answer was more clear to me initially and I accepted it before I saw your edit.