# How do I concatenate two macros with a dot between them without inserting spaces?

Tags: c-preprocessor

I'm preprocessing my InfoPlist file to include my revision number.  My header looks like this:

```
#import "svn.h"

#define APP_VERSION 1.0
#define APP_BUILD APP_VERSION.SVN_REVISION
```

When I check my build version from within the program, it's `1.0 . 123456`.  But if I try this:

```
#import "svn.h"

#define APP_VERSION 1.0
#define APP_BUILD APP_VERSION ## . ## SVN_REVISION
```

I get

```
error: pasting formed 'APP_VERSION.', an invalid preprocessing token
error: pasting formed '.SVN_REVISION', an invalid preprocessing token
```

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085594/how-to-concatenate-strings-with-c-preprocessor-with-dots-in-them) but it doesn't actually give an answer; the OP didn't actually need to concatenate the tokens.  I do.  How do I concatenate two macros with a dot between them without inserting spaces?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem looks like it is being caused by [a quirk of the preprocessor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html#Argument-Prescan): arguments to the concatenation operator aren't expanded first (or... whatever, the rules are complicated), so currently the preprocessor isn't trying to concatenate `1.0` and `.`, it's actually trying to paste the word `APP_VERSION` into the output token. Words don't have dots in them in C so this is not a single valid token, hence the error.

You can usually force the issue by going through a couple of layers of wrapper macros so that the concatenation operation is hidden behind at least two substitutions, like this:

```
#define APP_VERSION 1.0
#define SVN_REVISION 123456

#define M_CONC(A, B) M_CONC_(A, B)
#define M_CONC_(A, B) A##B

#define APP_BUILD M_CONC(APP_VERSION, M_CONC(.,SVN_REVISION))

APP_BUILD    // Expands to the single token 1.0.123456
```

You're in luck in that a C Preprocessor number [is allowed to have as many dots as you like](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Tokenization.html#Tokenization), even though a C float constant may only have the one.

Comment: it showing error as invalid suffix '.123456' on floating constant

Comment: @Abhishek are you compiling as well or just preprocessing? The main C language can't handle multi-dot numbers, so you need to make sure they end up in a string or otherwise hidden from it.