# How to include filename created by a macro

Tags: c, concatenation, c-preprocessor

I have the following define:

```
#define MY_CLASS MyClass
```

I'm trying to make a macro that will use MY_CLASS to expand to:

```
#include "MyClass.h"
```

Something like (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396139/how-do-i-concatenate-two-macros-with-a-dot-between-them-without-inserting-spaces) answer):

```
#define MY_CLASS MyClass
#define FILE_EXT h
#define M_CONC(A, B) M_CONC_(A, B)
#define M_CONC_(A, B) A##B
#define APP_BUILD M_CONC(MY_CLASS, M_CONC(.,FILE_EXT))
#include APP_BUILD
```

That one doesn't work though... I get these 3 errors:

```
Expected "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
Pasting formed '.h', an invalid preprocessing token 
Pasting formed 'MyClass.', an invalid preprocessing token
```

Is it possible to do it somehow?

Comment: Does this approach work for you? [C Macro - Dynamic #include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873722/c-macro-dynamic-include)

Comment: No idea how I missed that question... it's not exactly what I need and it took me a whilte to find out how to get rid of the prefix in the string (the "linux/compiler-gcc" part) but I finally managed with an empty #define. I guess I'll post the answer...

Comment: Are you sure the effort is worth the result?  `#define MY_CLASS_HDR "MyClass.h"` would be a lot simpler for everyone.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it's for a generic example of a library written for educational purposes for students that are not familiar with C++ templates yet and I thought it's slighty more elegant than making 2 `#define`'s for them to change (and would also nicely demonstrate some possible complexity of the preprocessor). Probably not gonna change anyone's course of life though :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to your Question: *If there's a more elegant / quicker (maybe 1 less macro definition?) solution*

```
#define STRINGIFY(X) #X
#define FILE_H(X) STRINGIFY(X.h)

//usage:

#define MY_CLASS MyClass
#include FILE_H(MY_CLASS)
//expands to: #include "MyCLass.h"

//or

#define ANOTHER_CLASS AnotherClass
#include FILE_H(ANOTHER_CLASS)
//expands to: #include "AnotherClass.h"
```

Well, if you need concatenation, then you have to add two extra lines:

```
#define CONCAT(A,B) CONCAT_(A,B)
#define CONCAT_(A,B) A##B

//could be extended like this:
//#define CONCAT3(A,B,C) CONCAT(CONCAT(A,B),C)
//...
```

Comment: Great, this indeed works, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I was referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20551609/2375105) in the comments (thanks @sj95126) which I originally missed. It didn't work as-is but I was able to deduce the right answer from it rather quickly...

This works:

```
#define MY_CLASS MyClass
#define EMPTY
#define MACRO1(x) #x
#define MACRO2(x, y) MACRO1(x##y.h)
#define MACRO3(x, y) MACRO2(x, y)
#include MACRO3(EMPTY, MY_CLASS)
```

If there's a more elegant / quicker (maybe 1 less macro definition?) solution I would be happy accept a different answer.