# C Preprocessor concatenation with variable

Tags: c, variables, concatenation, c-preprocessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C preprocessor and concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation)

Is it possible to concatenate a **C** preprocessor with a variable name?

```
#define  WIDTH 32

int dataWIDTH;


// dataWIDTH should be interpreted as 'data32'

printf("%d",dataWIDTH);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your use case requires a double-unescaping; using the token pasting (##) operator by itself will just append the name of the preprocessor directive.

```
#define WIDTH 32

#define _MAKEDATA(n) data##n
#define MAKEDATA(n) _MAKEDATA(n)

int MAKEDATA(WIDTH) = 7;
int _MAKEDATA(WIDTH) = 8;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%d\n", data32);
    return 0;
}
```

yields

```
$ gcc -E foo.c 
int data32 = 7;
int dataWIDTH = 8;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%d\n", data32);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation for an excellent discussion of the double-pasting "trick"

Answer (score 1):

There's a token pasting operator called ##, read about it for example here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09dwwt6y(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: The preprocessor expands this to `printf("%d", data##32)`, which yields a compiler error.  My understanding is that token pasting only works inside of macros.

Comment: That example was added by another user, the provided link shows how to use token-pasting from within a macro.