# C Preprocessor variable concatenation with "."

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor

I'm aware of multiple Q&As [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923425/c-preprocessor-concatenation-with-variable), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/how-to-concatenate-twice-with-the-c-preprocessor-and-expand-a-macro-as-in-arg)]that touch closely on this subject, and I've tried to implement their solutions but the fact that I need to use the . in my concatenation seems to be causing me trouble.

This is what I want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PROPERTY .value1
#define MAKE_PROP(var) var##PROPERTY

typedef struct {
    int value1;
    int value2;
} Node;

int main(void) {

    Node node;
    node.value1 = 1;
    node.value2 = 2;

    // MAKE_PROP(node) should evaluate to "node.value1".
    printf("%d", MAKE_PROP(node));

    return 0;
}
```

However it's giving me all sorts of errors. If I try the PASTER-EVALUATE idea from [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/how-to-concatenate-twice-with-the-c-preprocessor-and-expand-a-macro-as-in-arg)] then it tells me "pasting "." and "PROPERTY" does not give a valid preprocessing token".

Anyone know how to accomplish what I need? It's essential that it stays general and that I can use the `var` as this is something I'd like to call multiple times on different variable names.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but unless better named and well-documented using macros like this obfuscates the code and will make it harder to read, understand, and (most importantly) *maintain*. You will also need many `MAKE_PROP` and `PROPERTY` macros, one for each of the members of the structure.

Comment: How to concatenate strings with C preprocessor with dots in them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085594/how-to-concatenate-strings-with-c-preprocessor-with-dots-in-them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not working for two reasons:

1. The token concatenation operator suppresses the expansion of macros that are used as its operands. So you get `nodePROPERTY`. The solution to *that* is to add a level of indirection:

   ```
   #define PROPERTY .value1
   #define CONCAT(a, b) a##b
   #define MAKE_PROP(var) CONCAT(var, PROPERTY)
   ```

   Now `PROPERTY` is expanded *before* being fed as an argument to `CONCAT`.
2. The result of concatenating tokens must be a **single** valid token, but `node.value1` is 3 tokens (`node`, `.` and `value1`).

Now, it just so happens that you don't need concatenation at all, you just need to build the expression `(node .value1)` which can be done with following simple macros<sup>1</sup>:

```
#define PROPERTY value1
#define MAKE_PROP(var) ( (var).PROPERTY )
```

---

<sub>1: simplified with the help of [Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584518/lundin).</sub>

Comment: Ah I see, thanks a lot for the explanation! And thanks for the solution, it works perfectly!

Comment: In addition, it might be cleaner to `#define PROPERTY value1` and then `#define MAKE_PROP(var) ((var).PROPERTY)`

Comment: @Lundin - Yeah. Dunno what I was thinking, hopefully it looks less garbage now :)