# Glue constant with macro in C

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C preprocessor and concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation)

I have the macro

```
#define BUS B
```

I want to make macro `BUS_PORT` that expands to `PORTB`.

I did following:

```
#define BUS_PORT PORT ## BUS
```

But `BUS_PORT` expands to `PORTBUS`. What I did wrong? How to make it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation/1489985#1489985), you need an extra level of indirection. E.g.

```
#define BUS B
#define PASTER(x,y) x ## y
#define EVALUATOR(x,y) PASTER(x,y)
#define BUS_PORT EVALUATOR(PORT, BUS)
```