# C macro: concatenate symbols conditionally

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have

```
#define A_T 1
#define B_T 2
int x_a = 1, x_b =2;
```

How can I define a macro, which can concatenate the suffix _a and _b to the var name?

```
for example, something like this
#define A_T_SUF _a
#define B_t_SUF _b
#define SUFFIX(t) t ## _SUF 
#define VAR_SUF(var, t) var ## SUFFIX(t) 
.....
VAR_SUF(x, A_T) ---> be replaced to x_a
```

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C preprocessor and concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an extra indirection in the VAR_SUF macro to force it to evaluate the called macros before concatenating the tokens instead of concatenating first:

```
#define A_T_SUF _a
#define B_t_SUF _b
#define SUFFIX(t) t ## _SUF 
#define CAT(a, b) a ## b
#define XCAT(a, b) CAT(a, b)
#define VAR_SUF(var, t) XCAT(var, SUFFIX(t)) 
.....
VAR_SUF(x, A_T) ---> be replaced to x_a
```

without the extra indirect, `VAR_SUF(x, A_T)` would expand to `xSUFFIX(A_T)` (concatenate first, then look for more macros).  With the extra CAT/XCAT indirection, it will expand `SUFFIX(A_T)` first and then concatenate.

`XCAT` is short for `EXPAND_AND_CONCATENATE`, while `CAT` is just `CONCATENATE` (without expansion.)

**edit**

If `A_T` is also a macro (eg, `#define A_T  1`) then it will be replaced first.  You can avoid that by removing the indirection of the `##` in the SUFFIX macro:

```
#define A_T_SUF _a
#define B_t_SUF _b
#define CAT(a, b) a ## b
#define XCAT(a, b) CAT(a, b)
#define VAR_SUF(var, t) XCAT(var, t##_SUF) 
.....
VAR_SUF(x, A_T) ---> be replaced to x_a
```

This will cause that concatenation to happen first, then macros will be expanded, then the other concatenation will happen

If `x` is also a macro, then you have a problem, as there's no good way to expand one token and not the other before you concatenate them.

Comment: This does not seem to work. looks like A_T is always replaced with 1 first.

Comment: Yes, if `A_T` is also defined as a macro, then it will get replaced first.  Avoiding that requires doing SUFFIX directly rather than as a macro