# Usage of macro in C language

Tags: c++, c, macros

I need to concatenate strings using macros to generate function names.

```
#define CONCAT(a,b,c) a ## b

int i=1;
CONCAT(a,i)
```

This code gives `ai` as a result, while what I wanted is `a1`.

As there are many functions in my source code, I don't want to enumerate them.

My goal:

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    Funi1();//here i should be from  0 to one hundred 
    Funi2();
    Funi3();
    Funi4();
    ..
}
```

@Potatoswatter

I have written a script to expand it and the output file cost serval hundred lines. 
@Eric Finn

Comment: The replacement happens if preprocessing, before the compiler has any concept of a variable `i` with the value `1`. What are you actually trying to write?

Comment: I suggest you to read up on how (and when) the preprocessor works...

Comment: Please explain why you need a set of functions defined with macros, instead of a single function with an integer parameter. The way you described, it's not convincing that you really need what you're trying to do.

Comment: @hdante I want to avoid to write hardcode like that Fun11,Fun12,Fun13,..Fun21.. Therefore, I want to write macro to get the function name. In javascript, we can use `eval` convert string to command. However, in c language, I only find macro can work like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C preprocessor and concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation)

Comment: @YulongTian you didn't explain why the numbers can't be integer parameters.

Comment: @YulongTian What hdante means is just adding a new parameter to the function `void Fun(int num, ...)` and then for i = 0->99: `Fun(i, ...)`

Answer (score 8):

It is not possible since macros are expanded during pre-processing stage.
So, it can not take the value of a variable and concat.

Comment: @HotLicks What do you mean? If you mean a `#define` that won't work.

Comment: @Hot Licks How can I achieve it?

Comment: @mwerschy For there are hundred functions I need to concatenate, I don't want to enumerate them in my source code.

Comment: @YulongTian Why are you telling me that? And why do you have so many functions called `foo1` ... `foo999`? You may want to rethink your code...

Comment: These functions is generated by ecmangen(a tool for writing manifest file of etw) and I can't control it.

Comment: @YulongTian Perhaps you could write a program to write the code, then?

Comment: @YulongTian Then this is an XY problem: you're asking us about a proposed solution (Y), not the problem at hand (X). Show us the format of those functions and what you need to do, and then we can go from there to the preprocessor.

Comment: If you cannot modify the function declaration then put it in a function pointer array. `<type> Funptr[] = {Fun01, Fun02...}`/ After all, just call the array with index `Funcptr[i](...);`. If there is 100x100 functions like above then using a 2D array will be much faster

Answer (score 0):

what about `__COUNTER__` predefined macro, you have it on GCC and VC. Does it help you?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define FUNC2(x,y) x##y
#define FUNC1(x,y) FUNC2(x,y)
#define FUNC(x) FUNC1(x,__COUNTER__)

int FUNC(my_unique_prefix);
int FUNC(my_unique_prefix);

int main() {
   my_unique_prefix0 = 0;
   printf_s("\n%d",my_unique_prefix0);
   my_unique_prefix0++;
   printf_s("\n%d",my_unique_prefix0);
}
```

Example from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Things that only work once, then break, suck. Boost Preprocessor offers reusable mechanisms, but it's hard to help if we don't know what the goal is.

Answer (score 0):

you can pre-compile it with: gcc -E sourcecode.c and watch it, it just replace variable name, and not get value and calculate at all, so it's not possible to let it works like you want.

Answer (score 0):

try it with the ***LINE*** macro, it gives u numbers :) if u dont care about 1+1+1+1
like
static int FUNCADD(once,**LINE**)=1;if(FUNCADD(once,**LINE**)>0)

if that worx for u