# C Macro building with defines

Tags: c, macros

I am having trouble getting this macro expanison right

```
#define foo Hello
#ifdef foo
#define wrapper(x) foo ## x
#else
#define wrapper(x) boo ## x
#endif
```

calling:

```
wrapper(_world)
```

I would like the result of

```
Hello_world
```

however, the macro is treating the "foo" define as a literal, and thus giving

```
foo_world
```

Can someone point out my mistake?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of: [C preprocessor and concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend [gnu-cpp-manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html#Argument-Prescan) which clearly explains how macros are expanded.

Macro arguments are completely macro-expanded before they are substituted into a macro body, unless they(*macro arguments*) are stringified or pasted with other tokens (*by the macro function that is directly applied to*).

For example:

If an argument is stringified or concatenated, the **prescan** does not occur.

```
#define AFTERX(x) X_ ## x
#define XAFTERX(x) AFTERX(x)
#define TABLESIZE 1024
#define BUFSIZE TABLESIZE
```

`AFTERX(BUFSIZE) => X_BUFSIZE`: since `AFTERX` is to concatenate argument with prefix, its argument is not expanded, remaining `BUFSIZE`.

`XAFTERX(BUFSIZE) => X_1024`: `XAFTERX` does not do concatenation directly, so `BUFSIZE` will be expanded first.

Generally, arguments are scanned **twice** to expand macro called in them.

--- edit ---

So the better practice is: (code from [QEMU](http://www.qemu.org) source)

```
#ifndef glue
#define xglue(x, y) x ## y
#define glue(x, y) xglue(x, y)
#define stringify(s) tostring(s)
#define tostring(s) #s
#endif
```

`glue(x,y)` will concatenate `x` and `y` with both already expanded.

Comment: Many thanks!  I see the mistakes I have made, thank you teacher :)