# Macro using strings concatenation

Tags: c, string, macros, concatenation, c-preprocessor

I want to make a macro which doesn't use arguments but has predefined integer and string which is used.

I asked before about something similar with macro that has arguments and this is how it is:

```
#define BUZZER_PIN 1
#define BUZZER_PORT B
#define BUZZER_ALT 1

#define INIT_BUZZER_(PORTX, PIN, ALT)                                   \
    do {                                                                \
        PORT##PORTX##_PCR(PIN) = PORT_PCR_MUX(ALT) | PORT_PCR_DSE_MASK; \
        GPIO##PORTX##_PDDR |= (PIN)<<1;                                 \
       } while (0)

#define INIT_BUZZER(PORTX, PIN, ALT)                                    \
    INIT_BUZZER_(PORTX, PIN, ALT)
```

but what if I just want to have `INIT_BUZZER` that will be referenced to `INIT_BUZZER_` and do all above?

I tried to:

```
#define INIT_BUZZER INIT_BUZZER_(BUZZER_PORT, BUZZER_PIN, BUZZER_ALT)
```

I am always having problem only with string and I don't understand that part well.
If I call it this way I get `BUZZER_PORT` processed as string `BUZZER_PORT` not as the value of it = `B`

Comment: How about the stringify directive? `#BUZZER` will substiute to the value of the `BUZZER` macro surrounded by double quotes.

Comment: You cannot have two macros with the same name.

Comment: You aren't trying to define both versions of `INIT_BUZZER` at the same time, are you?

Comment: You can see its INIT_BUZZER and INIT_BUZZER_ so its different

Comment: The purpose of the original `INIT_BUZZER(...)` and `INIT_BUZZER_(...)` was to allow the arguments to `INIT_BUZZER` to be expanded before being passed to `INIT_BUZZER_`. You want instead a macro `INIT_BUZZER` that uses some canned parameters. Then, you should rename the old `INIT_BUZZER` to something else, and let your new `INIT_BUZZER` call that. I illustrate this in my answer.

Comment: See also [C preprocessor and concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation/).

Answer (score 2):

You need another macro to expand the macro arguments before it is passed to `INIT_BUZZER_`.

```
#define INIT_BUZZER_X(PORTX, PIN, ALT)                                    \
    INIT_BUZZER_(PORTX, PIN, ALT)

#define INIT_BUZZER INIT_BUZZER_X(BUZZER_PORT, BUZZER_PIN, BUZZER_ALT)
```

Now, when you use `INIT_BUZZER` in your code, it will first expand into `INIT_BUZZER_X` with the three arguments. The preprocessor will then proceed to process `INIT_BUZZER_X`, in which it will expand each of the three arguments, and pass them to `INIT_BUZZER_`.

Comment: Thank you it works. But it looks really difficult with these macros