# c macro, token pasting without quotes

Tags: c, macros

I need to generate some variable name with macro in C.
It seems that # token-pasting operator does the job, but the result is always a string.

```
#define     create_var( name )  char #name
```

will not work because name is expanding in "name" (as string).

```
#define     create_var( name )  char prefix##name
```

will work, but all my vars will have a prefix.

Is there any trick available to obtain a simple name?

`create(test)` to expand in

```
char test;
```

Thanks very much in advance,

Comment: `#define create(x) char x;`, perhaps?

Comment: thanks very much, I was just stuck not seeing the forest because of trees :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C preprocessor and concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation)

Answer (score 2):

If you would like your variable name to appear unmodified (without prefix) in your preprocessed code, just use the formal parameter name of the macro, without `#` and without `##`.

You can `#` in the macro definition if you want to convert some argument to a string constant. And can use `##` to concatenate tokens to build new tokens (for example to build new variable name with prefixes and/or suffixes and other stuff). With out any of these the preprocessor will just insert the sequence of tokens to pass to the macro unmodified (*).

(*): C preprocessor semantics ar subtle. Preprocessor macros are replaced at multiple stages during macro expansion which can have quite unobvious results.