# De-duplication of NSString & unichar constants

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, unicode, c-preprocessor

I have two simple constants:

1. `NSString` and
2. `unichar`,

defined as follows:

```
static NSString * const string = @"\u2022";
static unichar const character = 0x2022;
```

I'd want to have the number *0x2022* defined in one place.

I tried a lot of combinations (`#` and `##`, also `CFSTR` macro) with no success.

Can it be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "extracting a character"?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri I simplified the text. Hope it's clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Using ideas from [How to concatenate twice with the C preprocessor and expand a macro as in "arg ## _ ## MACRO"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation)):

```
#define STRINGIFY(_x_) #_x_

#define UNICHAR_FROM_HEXCODE1(_c_) 0x ## _c_
#define UNICHAR_FROM_HEXCODE(_c_) UNICHAR_FROM_HEXCODE1(_c_)

#define NSSTRING_FROM_HEXCODE1(_c_) @"" STRINGIFY(\u ## _c_)
#define NSSTRING_FROM_HEXCODE(_c_) NSSTRING_FROM_HEXCODE1(_c_)

#define MYCHARCODE 2022
static unichar const character = UNICHAR_FROM_HEXCODE(MYCHARCODE);
static NSString * const string = NSSTRING_FROM_HEXCODE(MYCHARCODE);
```

Preprocessed output:

```
static unichar const character = 0x2022;
static NSString * const string = @"" "\u2022";
```

(Note that `@"" "\u2022"` is equivalent to `@"\u2022"`.)

Comment: This works. It generates a warning though: _\u used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier_ for the 4th `#define`.

Comment: All right, I've figured it out. Simply pushed `ignored -Wunicode` for that one line. Thanks, man! Accepted. Perfect.