# How to add a prefix to a method with C macro (it's namespace purpose for Obj-C Category)?

Tags: c, macros

How to add a prefix to a method with C macro? For example:

```
#define CategoryName aNewCategory
#define Concatenate(prefix, methodName) prefix##_##methodName
#define AddCategoryPrefix(methodName) Concatenate(CategoryName, methodName)

@implementation NSObject(CategoryName)
+ (void) AddCategoryPrefix(logTask){
}
@end
```

The method name will be `CategoryName_logTask`, not `aNewCategory_logTask` as I want.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation

Comment: Thank you for your link! It helps a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate twice with the C preprocessor and expand a macro as in "arg ## \_ ## MACRO"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/how-to-concatenate-twice-with-the-c-preprocessor-and-expand-a-macro-as-in-arg)