# What does ## mean in C?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, c-preprocessor

I was looking at the source code of the berkeley lab checkpoint/restart and found this pre-process macro definition:

```
  #define io_wrap(_op,_ctx,_file,_buf,_count) \
        cr_##_op((_ctx)->req->errbuf,(_file),(_buf),(_count))
```

Any idea what the hell this thing means?

I found this in blcr-0.8.5/vmadump4/vmadump.h

Thank you!

Comment: _"what the hell this thing means"_ lol :D

Comment: It means concatenate `cr_` with the value of `_op()` without adding the whitespace which would be added if they were separated by a space character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's token concatenation. See the GCC manual: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html

And for some of its nitty gritty details, see this question: [How to concatenate twice with the C preprocessor and expand a macro as in "arg ## _ ## MACRO"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation)

Answer (score 2):

`##` is for concatenation in the C preprocessor.

This result `_op((_ctx)->req->errbuf,(_file),(_buf),(_count))` is concatenated with `cr_`