# Understanding recursive Macro Expansions

Tags: c, macros, embedded

I came across this question in an Embedded interview question set.

```
#define cat(x,y) x##y
```

concatenates `x` to `y`. But `cat(cat(1,2),3)` does not expand but gives preprocessor warning. Why?

Does C not encourage Recursive Macro expansions ? My assumption is the expression should display `1##2##3`.  Am i wrong ?

Comment: Recursive expansion works only for one level. See here: [Self Referencial Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Self-Referential-Macros.html#Self-Referential-Macros) and [Stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification)

Comment: I'm sorely tempted to close this as a duplicate of [C preprocessor and concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation), but there's just barely enough difference that I don't want to abuse the new god-like 'close-as-duplicate' powers that we've been given.  It won't take much encouragement, though.

Comment: The warning is correct; you can't combine a close parenthesis with a 3 and make a token, and token concatenation has to make a token.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I agree that it is not a duplicate of that, but ther's bound to be a dupe somewhere

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `cat(cat(1,2),3)` isn't expanded in a normal way which you expect that `cat(1,2)` would give `12` and `cat(12, 3)` would give `123`.

**Macro parameters that are preceded or followed by `##` in a replacement list aren't expanded at the time of substitution**. As a result, `cat(cat(1,2),3)` expands to `cat(1,2)3`, which can't be further expanded since **there is no macro named `cat(1,2)3`**.
So the simple rule is that, macros whose replacement lists depends on `##` usually can't be called in a nested fashion.