# Is it possible to define a macro from a macro

Tags: c++, c, macros

Here is what I am thinking.

```
#define prefix_1 1
#define prefix_2 2
#define prefix_3 3
```

And I want to define a macro using the prefixes above — like macro `macro_prefix_1` `macro_prefix_2` — and I expect them to turn into `macro_1` `macro_2`, etc. Just like the code below

```
#define macro_##prefix_1 I_am_macro_1
#define macro_##prefix_2 I_am_macro_2
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Succinctly, no.  At least, not like that.

Comment: Have you tried it? On gcc the -E option will give you the results of the preprocessor stage.

Comment: See [How to concatenate twice with the C preprocessor and expand a macro as in “`arg ## _ ## MACRO`”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/how-to-concatenate-twice-with-the-c-preprocessor-and-expand-a-macro-as-in-arg/1489985#1489985) for a detailed discussion of how token concatenation works.  You can't use `##` in the name of a macro as shown in the question; it must be in the expansion of a function-like macro.

Comment: Which is the difference from `#define macroA(x) I_am_macro_ ## x`? Then `macroA(2)` expands to `I_am_macro_2`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks, that helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you are trying to do is impossible. The (##) directive is impossible to use within a macro declaration. It is only possible to use it within the definition as such.

```
#define glue(a,b) a ## b
glue(c,out) << "test";
```

*Example borrowed from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/)*

Below, I have written an example of what you want to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define prefix_1 1
#define prefix_2 2
#define prefix_3 3

#define macro_##prefix_1 "macro_1"
#define macro_##prefix_2 "macro_2"
#define macro_##prefix_3 "macro_3"

int main(){
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", macro_prefix_1, macro_prefix_2, macro_prefix_3);
    return 0;
}
```

When you try to compile the above code you will get this build log.

```
||=== Build: Debug in file_test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
main.cpp|7|warning: missing whitespace after the macro name [enabled by default]|
main.cpp|7|error: '##' cannot appear at either end of a macro expansion|
main.cpp|8|warning: missing whitespace after the macro name [enabled by default]|
main.cpp|8|error: '##' cannot appear at either end of a macro expansion|
main.cpp|9|warning: missing whitespace after the macro name [enabled by default]|
main.cpp|9|error: '##' cannot appear at either end of a macro expansion|

main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
main.cpp|13|error: 'macro_prefix_1' was not declared in this scope|
main.cpp|13|error: 'macro_prefix_2' was not declared in this scope|
main.cpp|13|error: 'macro_prefix_3' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build failed: 6 error(s), 3 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

So if you want to be able to have macro's you will just have to add the prefix normally. Luckily you were basically already doing this, but adding "##". Hope this helped.