# Macro Concatenation with parameters

Tags: c, macros

I searched the forum but could not find a solution to this problem of macro contatenation with parameter. NOTE `var` is not a `macro` but a variable. Here is the issue:

`#define HELLO (var)   VALUE_ ## var`

when I call say `HELLO(1)`, I need the macro to be `VALUE_1` instead of `VALUE_var`.
Can this be done?

---

Hi Guys, 
   Thank you for your replies and pointers. I looked at the post before i posted the earlier one. My problem I guess is slightly different. May be I could not explain well. Here is what I want to achieve:

```
#define HELLO(var)      VALUE_ ## var
#define VALUE_1    // do something
#define VALUE_2    // do something
#define VALUE_3    // do something
```

In the code I want to use like this:

```
int i = 2;
HELLO(i);    // should convert to a macro VALUE_2
```

The problem is that when I pass a variable "i" to the marco, it should convert it to a number and concatenate. The previous post used the function name as a string and concatenates with a macro VARIABLE which is not the case here.

My problem is how to get the macro use the value of i and NOT "i" itself to generate another macro as VALUE_2.

I am sure it is possible or maybe I am missing something?

Thank You.

Comment: Search harder :)  You'll want to search for "preprocessor concatenation" and you'll get plenty of hits.

Comment: Here you find some discussion about this issue <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/how-to-concatenate-twice-with-the-c-preprocessor-and-expand-a-macro-as-in-arg>

Comment: Yes it can be done and you are almost correct except that there should not be space between HELLO and (var).

Comment: Guys please see the problem posted again.