# Using Macros to select function arguments

Tags: c++, gcc, macros, arduino

```
#define STRIP0 0
#define STRIP1 1
#define STRIP2 2
#define STRIP3 3
#define  PINS0 2,3,4
#define  PINS1 5,6,7
#define  PINS2 8,9,10
#define  PINS3 11,12,13

#define PINS(STRIP) { (STRIP) == (STRIP0) ? PINS0 :\
                      (STRIP) == (STRIP1) ? PINS1 :\
                      (STRIP) == (STRIP2) ? PINS2 :PINS3}
```

now if when i call a function that takes 3 arguments all of type int `foo(int,int,int);` like this `foo(PINS1);` then the function compiles and works as expected(all arguments are passed as if the #define was replaced by "5,6,7")

but if i use the macro for selecting the set of pins like `foo(PINS(STRIP1));` then the argument selection goes haywire. in this specific case the faulty argument list becomes "7,12,13" and for `foo(PINS(STRIP0));` it becomes "4,12,13" there is a pattern that i see but i dont have the expertise to tell and rectify what is happening at compile time.

Comment: If you use the `PINS` function-like macro you have two problems: The first is the curly-braces you have around the whole expression, The second is that instead of passing multiple arguments you pass a single argument because then the comma becomes nor an argument separator but the comma expression. You should reconsider your use of macros, any maybe use an `inline` function wrapper instead? Or at least modify the macro, maybe to take the function as an argument and have the call inside the macro "body"?

Comment: Why don't you just write an `if/else`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i will remove the curly braces and edit the question but it had no effect in the output.
when i do this `foo(PINS1);` (as specified in the question) the function takes the 3 numbers as arguments itself which led me to believe that the comma as expression wasnt happening instead compiler recognized that there are 3 arguments and that is why it proceeded.

this is the reason that i thought doing a macro that selects the `PINS0` or `PINS1` will work but it didnt.

your suggestion to have the function as an argument in the macro is probably what krzaq is suggesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imo you're hurting readability a lot by using macros for this. But here's how I'd do this:

```
#define STRIP0 0
#define STRIP1 1
#define STRIP2 2
#define STRIP3 3
#define  PINS0 2,3,4
#define  PINS1 5,6,7
#define  PINS2 8,9,10
#define  PINS3 11,12,13

#define CONCAT_HELP(A, B) A ## B

#define CONCAT(A, B) CONCAT_HELP(A, B)

#define PINS(FUNC,STRIP) FUNC(CONCAT(PINS, STRIP))
```

now, you'd call this like this:

```
PINS(foo, STRIP0);
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/KuI4nqyaM0rgQ3og)

You need two levels of indirection, because of the way macro replacement works ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1489985/2456565) is an in-depth explanation). With just `#define CONCAT(A,B) A ## B`, `CONCAT(PINS,STRIP0)` would create `PINSSTRIP0` which makes no sense here.

---

For completeness sake, if you expect to use this with runtime values (of which you gave no indication of in the question), you could go with a helper function template that would switch over the strip value:

```
template<typename Func>
void pins(Func f, int strip)
{
    switch(strip){
    case 0: f(PINS0); break;
    case 1: f(PINS1); break;
    case 2: f(PINS2); break;
    case 3: f(PINS3); break;
    }
}
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/coEqvVJWb5wLOoUz)

and, if you have C++17 available:

```
constexpr tuple<int,int,int> params[] = {
    make_tuple(PINS0),
    make_tuple(PINS1),
    make_tuple(PINS2),
    make_tuple(PINS3)
};

template<typename Func>
void pins(Func f, int strip)
{
    apply(f, params[strip]);
}
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UzWrIVsHiVZpOQhZ)

though at this point, the helper function stops being necessary.

Comment: I definitely needed my coffee. Good answer, but maybe it's pertinent to explain *why* an intermediate expansion is required. The OP doesn't seem to be well versed.

Comment: @StoryTeller added.

Comment: the objective that i'm trying to accomplish is that each PINS0 set corresponds to a different set of physical pin connections that do not change at runtime and need to be passed as arguments to various functions
so by doing something like this i will save the trouble of changing these definitions everywhere thats all! 
i'll try your answer looks like it should work
@StoryTeller i am not very well versed for sure thanks everyone for their help ;-)