# Difference between cpp and gcc -E

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

I thought that both `cpp foo.c` and `gcc -E foo.c` do preprocess the source file the same way, but I got their output to differ for the same file.

```
$ cat foo.c
#define VARIABLE 3
#define PASTER(x,y) x ## _ ## y
#define EVALUATOR(x,y)  PASTER(x,y)
#define NAME(fun) EVALUATOR(fun, VARIABLE)

extern void NAME(mine);
```

Result for `cpp`:

```
$ cpp foo.c
# 1 "foo.c"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 329 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "foo.c" 2





extern void mine ## _ ## 3;

$
```

Result for `gcc -E` and for `clang -E`:

```
$ gcc -E foo.c
# 1 "foo.c"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 330 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "foo.c" 2





extern void mine_3;
$
```

Why do those outputs differ, and which one should I use when I want to see the preprocessed source ?

Original code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/how-to-concatenate-twice-with-the-c-preprocessor-and-expand-a-macro-as-in-arg)

Comment: I just tried this.  My version of `cpp` produces identical output as `gcc -E`.  Same as your `gcc` output.

Comment: I get the same results with `cpp foo.c` as with `gcc -E foo.c`. Can you paste the output of `cpp -v foo.c` into the question?

Comment: If I use `--traditional-cpp` as a command line parameter to cpp, i get the same output as yours.  Looks likes someone already identified that as a likely answer.

Comment: The first line of `cpp -v foo.c` is `Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)`. Rest of output is quite verbose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between the two is that `gcc -E` will eliminate `-traditional-cpp`. If you include the option then you should receive the same result as `cpp`.

↳ https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Traditional-Mode.html

Comment: Indeed. How does gcc manage to eliminate this option as there is no `-no-traditional-cpp` ?

Comment: Looks like some `cpp` programs (like the one on my workstation) are built to not default to `-traditional-cpp`.  So if you want to turn off traditional mode when invoking `cpp`, any idea how to do it?  My version complains if I try to use `-no-traditional-cpp` or `--no-traditional-cpp`. This is just academic for me since invoking `gcc -E` instead does the trick.

Comment: @Bilow: `gcc` typically eliminates it unless specified otherwise.

Comment: I will use `gcc -E` but I'm still wondering how gcc does eliminate `-traditional-cpp` since I can't do it in command line

Comment: Thank you all for the answers